# Erratic "view more" behavior in profile page reputation summary

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-summary

First, a little game. Please spot the difference between those two screenshots: (FHRC will come later)

> [image]     [image]

Hint: two words.

Giving up? OK OK... it's the "view more" link leading to their reputation tab. Both have no recent positive reputation changes however one showing the link and the other does not show it.

The bug is the right one, it should show "view more" only when there are at least five items, for example:

> [image]

As far as I could dig up, the cause for this is the one to the right (with the link) had recent **negative** reputation change, as seen in [his reputation tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130598/byron-whitlock?tab=reputation):

> [image]

Can we please have no more the view more when we do not need it anymore? :)

Comment: What happens when you click the "view more" link when there are none to view? Have you reproduced the issue, or (more likely) found other profiles to confirm it's definitely recent negative rep change causing it?

Comment: @James to reproduce click the image to the right, you'll get to the user's profile page with the link. Clicking "view more" leads to the reputation tab as expected, no bug there.

Answer (score 2):

Seems there's more to it...

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/237288/dhara-shah
That user has negative rep change today too, but no link.

USER:
byron-whitlock
ACTUAL REP CHANGE:
-3 today
MAIN PROFILE PAGE:

> This user has no recent positive reputation changes
>   view more

USER:
dhara-shah
ACTUAL REP CHANGE:
-4 today
MAIN PROFILE PAGE:

> -48    Mail feature on SO :O

The bit I mainly don't get is why on byron-whitlock's main profile page it doesn't show the link and rep for the question they posted as per dhara-shah. ie show:
-3 Can we filter questions by reputation

The only differences I see are, byron-whitlock has some **positive rep today** too, whereas dhara-shah doesn't, and byron-whitlock's question was 2009 (maybe old script or wtf?)

Weird. Sure someone looking at the script(s) will see the reason.

Comment: I think it's per-post so the net change for byron is -3 which is still negative.

Comment: Quite possibly. tbh my brain has checked out for the day, or I'd have maybe looked at it more and compared more users. Someone with access to the scripts, or more knowledge, will see straight away what's occurring.