# New responsive Activity page

Tags: discussion, profile-page, announcements, responsive-design

**Update 2 - December 8, 2021:** We’ve shipped a bunch of refinements over the last 24 hours or so. We’re going through the bugs and design requests and marking them with the proper tags. There’s a lot here, so it’ll take us a minute. We’ve done the following to address your design feedback in the near term:

1. Switched to the smaller version of questions / answers from the Profile page, thus changing the font size.
2. Reduced the padding on individual items while maintaining this newer aesthetic.
3. Grouped questions, answers, tags, and reputation as columns again.
4. Upstreamed a [smaller font size](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/commit/98770709c12b3fc0be43f29da9adc2463a6b3e8b) to our design system’s [post summary](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/) component.
5. Various smaller visual refinements.

**Update 1 - December 7, 2021:** This was rolled out on Stack Overflow and all Stack Exchange network sites.

After receiving and incorporating feedback the community (thank you!) we’ve launched the responsive Activity page!
The most common feedback we received was that we’re straying too far from a summary for the summary view. This feedback was not only valuable but also correct!

We reconsidered the value of information shown on post summaries and condensed them significantly from our initial redesign. We also made tons of little tweaks and fixes along the way. We’ll be triaging bug reports as they come and we know there’s still room for improvements, so suggestions are welcomed and encouraged! Thank you in advance!

---

**Original post - November 19, 2021:**

In our continued effort to [deprecate our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views), we’ve turned our attention to the Activity page. We’re planning on shipping the changes <s>next week</s> *sometime soon* and wanted to show it off first.

Check out this [5 minute tour](https://youtu.be/1hPjjvp4b8I) of the Activity page and let us know what you think. The feedback we’ve received so far has been invaluable, not only in identifying bugs, but also in helping us reflect and be thoughtful about the changes we’re making.

### What’s new?

#### Horizontal navigation turns vertical

The navigation includes all the same items but is now placed vertically to the left of the column of sections to fix moments like this. It’ll allow us to add more functionality in the future without breaking the layout or introducing any wrapping.

[image: horizontal navigation on the activity page]

#### Two columns become one

The most obvious change might be the switch to a single column for Activity sections. All of the same (and a little additional) information is here, but now it’s within a single column that squishes comfortably all sorts of browser widths.

#### Post summaries

We’ve switched post summaries to use the [post summary component in our design system](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/#minimal). In the process, we’ve added more details about each post such as views, answer counts, tags, and an answer excerpt on answers. This component has been designed to be responsive and show information in a compact but digestible format.

[image: new post summary component in wide browser window]
[image: new post summary component in mobile-width browser window]

#### Summary stays on “Summary”

Quick reference information will only be shown on the Summary page (which is the base Activity page). It made sense to show “Summary” on Summary and to not show it elsewhere. Less stuff to scroll past to get to the stuff you want to on other Activity pages.

[image: activity answer page without summary section]

#### A handful of other changes

In this process, a lot of little things were tweaked and polished. This includes empty states, improvements to the reputation changes view, accessibility improvements, and much more. No functionality has been lost so if you find anything broken, missing, or out of place, please let us know. We appreciate it!

[image: redesigned activity page shown in both wide browser window and mobile-width]

Comment: Voting "System" is a bit biased, I can only cast Upvotes but no Downvotes (on Qt + Answer(s)), because Rep<100. But I don't like this upcoming Change: Too much Vertical-Scrolling... And I suppose the 'Activity' Tab will then probably soon become as "unusable" as the 'Profile' Tab (in FF55) where only the first 5-6 Lines are visible before greying out and where I need to read the Content from the HTML-Source as the 'Responsiveness' cannot be switched/toggled off for that Tab...

Comment: @chivracq Note that [Firefox 55 is not supported, officially](//browsers.stackoverflow.design/).

Comment: @SebastianSimon, yeah-yeah, I know of course, and it's "cute" to see 'Stack' and 'SO' "experiment" with all new Syntax and Func that don't work anymore in v[-2] Browser Versions. (And I use FF55 "only" because my Default/Prod Browser (PM26, not even listed on that Support Page) works even worse since about 1y, ah-ah...! Can't even upvote anymore in that one, regardless of Rep...) [Specialist in Web-Automation, I have "my Reasons" to not use any of the Browsers listed..., I rely on "other" Technologies... => Check my Profile (if you can read it...!) for more Info...]

Comment: Somehow I missed this thread entirely until just now. With features like flexbox and grid solidly supported for a few years now, can you speak to why desktop users are forced into this one column layout now? It probably works *great* for mobile users, but it's a clear and *huge* regression for people with bigger screens, like laptop and desktop users. I mean, here is a comparison (granted, MSE vs SO, but still): https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNRcM.png On the old layout, I can see 6 full sections. On the new layout, I can see... 1 section and a little bit extra.

Comment: Why am I only able to change which tag badge to track on some of my sites? On the ones I can't it lists the "top tag".

Comment: In addition to the tablet optimized size of objects which alone makes this a horrible experience, most of the summaries are now presented to the right on my desktop screen instead of in the middle. Why?

Comment: @Werner You need to click the gear icon to the right of “Next privilege” to track you next tag badge instead. This has always been the case and is unrelated to these changes.

Comment: Please explain what the yellow colour for some of the post in the "Bookmarks" means. If it's the fact that there was a change to the post since I last checked it out, then that completely fails to be conveyed. And if it really is the case, please let us get to turn it off. I mean I really don't want to have to load every single one to get rid of the yellow. One of mine has the date of "Aug 24 '08 at 5:19", and my account is not that old, so I'm really unsure what it is.

Comment: I use the all actions view to look at the comments I've made so I can check questions that interested me and see if there was a resolution. This new view is much less usable for me than the old one. Everything is way too tall. Why does the time need it's own line? Put that next to the type of action.  The votes view is also full of wasted space.  I don't see a way to see individual flags I've raised either, just the number of helpful. Not a fan of this new layout.

Comment: Man, I read this whole thread several times a few weeks back, and somehow it had never dawned on me that any of this would affect *me* on *desktop*. It was framed as improving something about mobile users, so I didn't worry about it too much. Now that it's been deployed to SO...yeah, I hate it. It feels big and clunky and mobile-like, even though I'm on a 4K monitor. So much less information :/

Comment: The fonts, size, proportions, positions gives much strain on eyes. Is there any way to bring it back to normal? atleast to someone who opts to?

Comment: What is responsive on a page with the whole content in one column? WIde screen, narrow screen - all looks the same. The same unusable.

Comment: @Glorfindel That's a good list of issues that people have noticed with the new activity page. Consider changing back to the old activity page in a week and create a similar list for things people find annoying. "_The new activity page had this and that which I really liked_" etc. Then implement _those_ things if there's a broad support for them.

Comment: Comments on this post took the usual (wrong) direction, so it's time to remind everyone: "I hate this", "you suck" and other personal attacks are *not* how [constructive criticism of a design change is supposed to look](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314089). If you do think you have anything constructive to add, see if it isn't already posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372698), and consider writing an answer, the character limit there gives you much more room to be constructive than the comments. Remember the Code of Conduct and keep the subtle put-downs out of these comments.

Comment: Late for the party, but I'll explain my downvote: you made awesome work with the view for mobiles and small screens, but in the process made it appear **way worse than before** on PC with big screen, which is what I happen to use. Enormous amounts of whitespace, and overall feeling it's a page designed *only* for mobile.

Comment: I archived some of the conversation about comment moderation on this post/MSE to chat. I invite other people that want comment moderation on MSE explained to them to drop by [this chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1619) so we won't drown out any potentially useful feedback by these conversations. If there's any more questions, I'm there.

Comment: Everything is way too big, when I open a profile page I practically see nothing of interest to me because everything is big enough to read it from across the room, but nothing is really shown! This doesn't make anything more clear or less cluttered, it just adds to scroll wheel wear! (this is on a 1600x900 14" screen)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413558/why-was-the-profile-page-changed-to-be-objectively-worse-lower-information-den

Comment: I downvoted because: (1) The new design is, at first glance at least, terrible: vastly less information per unit area, to no apparent benefit. (2) The oblivious disconnect in tone between "We implemented this awesome new feature we're sure you'll love, isn't it great?" versus the nearly unanimous actual feedback the feature is receiving.

Comment: The deployment isn't even consistent - in all of the stacks that I'm a member of ***except [linguistics.se]***, Answers are shown first; on that one exception, Questions.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin This seems it may be intentional (don't know if useful): For users that have more questions than answers on a site, it looks like questions are the first to be shown (e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/260800/ooker?tab=topactivity shows me questions first too) You have more answers than questions everywhere, except Linguistics.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That's not how the question/answer section order works. The display order of those sections varies *by user*, not by site. The system displays whichever of those sections first which it feels is more important *for that user*. This was the behavior in the old layout too. I didn't notice it until 1.5 years ago when I became a moderator on SO and started visiting a *lot* of profiles. I, eventually, added some CSS to maintain a consistent order for all profiles, because having them in different orders is a pain in the rear when looking at more than one profile.

Comment: Related 9 year old feature request: [Use "score" instead of "votes" in the list of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153515/273494) All over the activity page score is referred to as "votes".

Comment: This design is perfect... for vertically oriented screens around 3 inches wide. The problem is the bulk of use on this site isn't on mobile devices, it's on desktop. People are asking questions and seeking help while coding. The old design was far better on desktop screens - this one takes up too much space, uses too large of fonts, and requires a lot of horizontal eye tracking and vertical scroll to read anything - not to mention much of what was on the page is lost, like seeing more than 5 tags or accounts.

Comment: Like others said, this is a major turn off. *Horizontal goes vertical*? But I am using a 16:9 screen. Exclusively. Horizontal is a desirable. And I thought *responsive* means roughly the same is *easily configurable by the user*.

Comment: @Jyrki-NoShog9-NoSE responsive design means the look, layout, and sometimes content changes based on the space available to display it - it has nothing to do with user control, other than you can control the size of your browser window. For example tiling your browser to half your screen's width, the summary section goes from 3 1/3 width side by side boxes to 3 full width vertically stacked sections.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the explanation. But I want it to also "respond" to available extra width. If I increase the width of the window all I get is more white space. I want more information. The list of tags used to fit on 4 screens. Now it takes 11. Just go back to the old.

Comment: When viewing my answers why would I need to see more than three lines of text per answer? The question title, and my vote count suffice. The vote count (something I find interesting) is now miniscule, and the extra text now shown is largely useless to me. If that extra contains a displayed equation, it consumes a lot of space and there is room for possibly  only 4 answers per screen. I would like a compressed list of 25, please. Make it a design goal to minimize white space. 20 per cent max.

Comment: Why not *Two columns become four!*?

Comment: As someone who typically spends hours a day in stackoverflow and a lot of time watching activity in my reputation page (609k reputation), the newest changes are way less usable. I work on a 36" screen and it feels like there's only about 1/3 the amount of information on my screen now and things always start out collapsed, causing **more clicks to see less information**. This is a worse UI in all regards on the desktop with a decent size screen than what we had before - please put it back. I actually thought some setting must have been accidentally changed, but no, I'm stuck with this.

Comment: The above was an optimistic view from me. My list of tags now takes 11 pages according to the profile page. **But each of those 11 pages requires scrolling worth approximately 4 screen heights.** It used to fit on 4 pages. **So the information density dropped by a factor of 11 :-(** What used to be available upon request by right-click (or was it just mouse-over), if needed, is now displayed prominently.

Comment: When this plan was first announced why was it not PROMINENTLY explained that it applies also to users others than those on mobile devices? I'm sure you would have gotten most of today's feedback in due time that way rather than having to face today's critical sh*#¤%storm. I feel bad about airing my displeasure in a non-constructive way, but I cannot help it. This update is simply awful on my laptop. Even before the update there was too much whitespace on the sides, and now it is much worse.

Comment: Combining Questions and Answers into two columns was a good move, but i'd like to see that for the others as well, given they're all designed to shrink to mobile width anyway. Reputation/Votes Cast, Bookmarks/Followed, Accounts/Bounties

Comment: A serious question: Was there any consideration given to UX and not just UI? The new design looks pretty but much of it is super hard to use now. I had to go hunting on my own profile for an answer I had posted and the [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663001/davidg?tab=answers) page is so fiddly and complicated now.

Comment: @Jyrki-NoShog9-NoSE _“If I increase the width of the window all I get is more white space”_ — Which is why most of us don’t consider this redesign to be _responsive_, but _mobile-only_. _“When this plan was first announced why was it not PROMINENTLY explained that it applies also to users others than those on mobile devices?”_ — I knew it was coming to desktop. That’s what responsiveness is supposed to mean: one unified design for all devices. The first answers to the announcement (from before it was shipped) already suggested to decrease the whitespace and increase the information density.

Comment: @Andrew The new layout isn't exactly ideal on a phone screen, either. Eg, comments get chopped rather short, with no way to expand them (of course you can visit the page the comment comes from, but that's pretty tedious when you're doing a comment search). I used one of your comments as a demo in [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372772/334566), I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I have changed my upvote to a downvote. Initially, it looked like you were going to provide improvements, but after it went live and I saw how bad it looked like I change my vote. I think the majority agrees that more whitespace is a bad thing. We want to see as much information as quickly as possible. We don't want to scroll or press secondary buttons to load more content.

Comment: After years being on SO, I joined Meta SE **today** to request: please rollback.  Please.   I had no complaints about the old layout.  While the new design looks nice, it's difficult to use.   Great on phones, but consider, how many people are coding on their phones?  So again, please rollback.  Please.  Thank you.

Comment: I think there's a regression in [rep graph on-hover bar highlight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372804) because the highlight isn't working anymore although the bug has been marked status-completed.

Comment: bug: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312087/haskell-why-is-alternative-implemented-for-list/70312261#70312261) shows up green in the answers panel on the user's [summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625403/amalloy?tab=summary), but it is not an accepted answer.

Comment: @WillNess been meaning to report this too, oddly (or not, given the state of this fiasco) it still displays correctly on mobile (chrome on iOS).

Comment: I really don't understand your... obsession with useless white space. Since the infamous line-height change, every single layout change seems to introduce more and more useless blank space everywhere. And SE keeps doing it, regardless all the negative feedback. I saw the new page just today, and OMG, do we really need all this padding and spacing everywhere? I downvoted this and agree with all answers below that are complaining about this excessive spacing

Comment: @WillNess Not just that answer; others that show up in the summary section show as accepted when they are not, for that user. Haven't checked any other users. If there isn't a bug report below (check the bugs section of the top answer), please do post one.

Comment: @TylerH that bug has been reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372749/241919). In summary, if the question has an accepted answer, then *all* answers on that question will be shown as accepted.

Comment: @hkotsubo personally, I'm grateful for "the infamous line-height change" because for me it made  SO pages much easier to read, for some reason. but this one here, is an unmitigated disaster.

Comment: The nav menu for this section being on the left side is pretty awful.

Comment: Almost as infamous as the ["vanity metrics" one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive) (with an unspecific title). 193 answers seem to be some kind of record(?).

Comment: Dan, is it intentional that the number of "helpful flags" is not shown on **other user's** profiles in the [Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) (in the "Impact" box) - I can still see my own but we used to be able to see the number cast by other users (exact number). --- We can guess the number of flags roughly by looking at their badges, so why hide the exact number (which sometimes exceeds 500, and the ability to guess via the badges available). Thanks.

Comment: It has been over a month since this has been rolled out and indicators for post status: closed, deleted are still missing. This is huge problem for people who follow post in order to moderate them. This is also a problem low reputation users that are approaching the Q ban or are banned, because they cannot see whether their own questions are closed or not when they visit the list and would like to improve posts.

Comment: Am I reading this right? **235 answers** have been posted? And it seems 50 of them (more or less) are about **very trivial imperfections** but that's my very personal layperson's view. P.S How does someone know if their feature request, constructive criticism or bug report hasn't already been mentioned by some other user? Who has the time to scan 235 answers-eeek!

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's what the [table of contents](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372698/786798) is for :) Which is telling by itself. However, you can see several [tag:duplicate] posts there already - so clearly not everyone takes the time to scan all the answers

Comment: @OlegValter  Behold the English expression ["**laundry list**"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437507/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-laundry-list) shall henceforth be known as  ***table of contents***.

Comment: @Mari-LouA with answers spanning multiple pages, I think we are firmly in the table of contents territory :)

Comment: I just saw that you’re [fixing the Segoe UI baseline](//github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/863), which would fix many alignment bugs such as [this one](/a/372673/289905).

Comment: After using the new layout for several months, I have to say I find it really confusing and hard to use compared to the last one. I can't figure out where to see what flags I've raised recently, that used to be in the last UI but I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: @jrh You should be able to reach them by clicking on [the flag count in the "impact" box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/667KZ.png) (although this is admittedly never indicated in the UI in any way). Your flag page is also always reachable via https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current

Comment: @zcoop98 thanks, I found it after poking around and finding the person who complained about the link not being clearly labeled, I upvoted that post, I never would have guessed that was clickable in a million years. I kinda miss the 1990s "underline every link" style now.

Comment: I was thinking about it more and it's not *just* the flags that I find to be less than great. The "view all X [answers, votes, etc.]"  sections do not look clickable to me either. I do not understand what is meant to be "clickable" about a small, gray piece of text, among a bunch of more obvious buttons. I think we're beyond the "cheese moving" stage now, even months in I literally just scan right past that text. I get that there's some trend towards "minimalism" or something that made people get rid of the 90s underlines but this new design is going *way too far* in my opinion.

Comment: Easiest fix would be to make that text blue or something. Why isn't it blue? The "view more" text used to be. Other stuff in the UI is blue, like "You have no active **bounties**", "You have not created any **articles**". Right now it's the same level of emphasis as the time that a thing was posted, which is *not clickable* and not all that important either. Also I guess while I'm typing this, the whole SO interface feels significantly more "monochrome" now, a bit more color wouldn't hurt honestly.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

## Summary of bugs / feature requests posted as answers

Want to contribute? Great! But please read the notes at the bottom of this post first.

| Type | Summary | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Negative reputation changes show as "+-[x]" instead of as "-[x]"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372596/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [No vote counts in the "questions" and "answers" section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372597/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Summary Overflow™ in tooltip description of "people reached"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372601/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Unexpected word "pretty" when expanding reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372604/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Add back the numbers indicating how much reputation changed or how many responses were received on the tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372611/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Downvotes are green, not red on the reputation page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372631/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Missing closing parenthesis in the bounty expiration message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372696/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Expand 'Today' in reputation history by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372690/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Unclear what the green bars above the reputation history are meant to represent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372603/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Random paragraph-returns in post titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372636/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Attempting to expand reputation history entries for specific posts expands the wrong one, or outright fails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372620/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Not Every Element Needs Its Own Line](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372695/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Sorting Questions by Views no longer actually shows the views for each question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372662/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [No bar highlight on hover in reputation graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372804) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Deleted answers don't show up in red anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372629/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Answers tab has a wider table than the rest of the tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372646/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Columns in Reputation graph are highlighted upon clicking but no function is performed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372692/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [The text of the "Track the next one" button is hardly visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372622/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Answer text hard-wraps on "answer" tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372763) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Timestamps in All actions tabs align by end of title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372874) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Followed posts start with an empty line if the post title is long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372614/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [+2 for Wiki Tag Edit does not show text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372600/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Answer text shows HTML escapes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372626/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Posts edited lost precision in impact section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372663/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Badges page has a single badge in last row](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372810) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Answer section shows votes and acceptance state of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372716/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Change "up votes" to "upvotes" and "down votes" to "downvotes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372728/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Expand comments in all actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372772) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | ["next badge" badge icon out of place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373043) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Wheels to track next privilege and badge are vertically misaligned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372632/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Select Next badge modal not usable in mobile devices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372751/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Numbered changes are not centered in blue badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372673/) | [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | ["next badge" block displaced after selecting another badge to track](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372609/) | [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [After sorting reputation history by post, no posts are displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372668/) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | ['x prior review suspensions' overflows on smaller screens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372625/) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | ['Follow post' functionality is FUBAR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372645/) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | ["Next privilege" messed up for some users on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372610/) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [After switching to "track a tag badge", the badges popup doesn't show](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372613/) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Wrong pluralization: "1 answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372639/) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Questions on many tabs are shown as having '1 bookmarks'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372641/) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Entries in the list of tags on the Summary page and the Tags page say "1 posts"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372644/) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Lost indication of closed / duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372701/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [On some sites, the graph in the reputation widget is pushed down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372637/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [MathJax wraps awkwardly on the activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372605/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [The font size and padding in the lists for the Summary are enormous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372606/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Choosing a new tag badge to track is not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372633/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Bring back color difference for visited links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372651/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Inconsistency in punctuation between sections without items in activity summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372676/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Insufficient contrast between text and background on chip for questions with accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372683/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Poor information architecture on the Answers page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372684/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Reputation graph does not load on Area 51 Discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372638/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Profile is showing the question score for my answers, not the answer score](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Expansion and contraction of posts in votes tab leaves a bigger box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372755) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Color inconsistency in reputation sorted by post and time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372761) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Answers and Questions section misalign when one of them is more than summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372777) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Answers in are all show as being accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372749) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Rows between tags and reputation sections are misaligned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372807) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Bottom row in Tags section has too much height](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372809) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Changes from votes that don't affect reputation no longer show in the reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372623/) | [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) (?) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Tag-badge cog leads to wrong badges pop-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372724/) | [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [No full stop on subtabs in Votes tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372694/) | [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Bookmarks of deleted questions don't have a deleted background colour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372782) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Differing label alignments in tabs of a All actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372863/) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [A post's score is shown as "votes" instead of "score"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372652/) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Summary page no longer shows scores of answers and questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372658/) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Redesign looks weird on bigger screens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372682/) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Left and right arrows from a scrollbar appear under expandable content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372726/289905) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Question count total should include hidden questions for mods/self](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372741) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Bar spacing in reputation graph not uniform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372802) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Labels in All actions page are misaligned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372817) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Suggested edits' results are in the wrong tense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372795) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Bookmarks page doesn't link to most recent activity when sorted by Activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372831/) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Answer timestamp overflowing container](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372812) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [The only part of the activity that isn't responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372836) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Missing tooltip and tooltip style inconsistency in impact section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372850/) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Research Assistant can line wrap in badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372851/) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Reputation graph disappears at lower resolutions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372868) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Dot in badges is misaligned in summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372870) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Dot in badges is cut off -](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372869) *["the bling"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372869)* [does it again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372869) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Columns in Votes cast stop being aligned at lower resolutions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372872) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Followed answers are shown as their question instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372864/) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [The reputation graph's selection feature is broken in Safari](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372786) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Posts background on different listings do not change when the post is deleted.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372950/) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Tooltip for tracking rep / privileges is too narrow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373027/376026) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Badge names are too low in badges section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374347) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Newest title is misaligned with Next Badge title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374345) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Locked icons in impact section misaligned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374344) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Fonts misaligned in section titles and View all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374343) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [First line in rep mini graph is shorter than the others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374358) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Recent tag rep gain in summary has low alignment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374374) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Next tag badge counters have different alignment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374381) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Fix the faint yellow coloring of the new reputation events when sorting by Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372934) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Descenders are cut off in Navigation drop down list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374430) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Reputation box doesn't list reputation increases for accepting answers as correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372862) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [In Activity / Reputation changes of questions vs answer are not distinguished](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374475) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Tab separators in post sections are slightly thicker sometimes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374516) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Reputation gained since tooltip has empty space in right margin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374566) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Different alignments between scores and button text in Summary and Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374570) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [View all activity pages title has small margin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374626) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Y-axis label of reputation graph has insufficient letter spacing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374819) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Next badge dialogue scrollbar doesn't have margin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374859) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [In reopen votes cast timestamp is out place if user has only cast 1 vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374882) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [A single answer doesn't align with the center of the section.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374884) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Tooltips in impact section have different levels of alignment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374902) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [# of votes not vertically aligned in list with deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375073/295232) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Highlight of Track next tag badge close button gets stuck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375096) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [The requested tag does not exist in choose next badge dialogue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375094) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Choosing a new regular badge to track is not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375146) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Badges and rep are misaligned with site name in Accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375155) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Top tag and Next privilege bar misalign in smaller resolutions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375158) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Awarded badges aren't centered in the boxes of select tag badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375164) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Navigation title font too small at very low resolutions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375177) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Remove bookmark tooltip has too much margin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375188) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Unfollow tooltip has too much margin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375189) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Tag badges for tags with long names overflow their container in Next badge dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375374/295232) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Deleted posts are no longer highlighted in the "Following" tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375828/277866) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Missing space between bounty amount and opening parenthesis in the 'Bounties' tab in my profile's 'Activity' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375837/986753) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Reputation change indicator activity page doesn't include reputation restored from deleted posts, causing it to show an inaccurate number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/376253#376253) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Bring back the highlitht of deleted posts in Following tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377304/277866) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Status of Review and Suggestions under "All actions" are too action-y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372612/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add vertical separator between daily bars in the reputation graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372608/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Reduce height of unused sections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372747/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Badges icons are not perfectly aligned if group is empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372748) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Include code blocks inside table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372616/) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [The "summary" page is too information-rich to be a summary anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372060/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Summary requires too much scrolling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372073/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Tags tab has too much empty space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372619/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [More contrast in expand arrow on hover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375176) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Site icons and names could be center aligned consistently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375160) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Make check mark green in positive question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375112) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Make cross mark red in negative question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375113) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Make distance between cogs and labels consistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375080) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Larger fonts and 3 columns in "Select your next badge" dialogue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374816) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Rows in Votes cast have too much spacing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372861) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Can labels in All actions have more color](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372818) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Correct spacing between rep/badge/impact sections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372806) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [See votes on recent questions in the summary tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372598/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Re-add link to network profile in case of hidden accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372599/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Make it clear that most statistics in the Impact box are hyperlinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372602/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Bring back UTC timestamp when hovering over the time field in the Reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372630/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Show last activity date/time at the bottom right of the bookmark entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372635/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Duplicate date entry in reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372642/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Timestamp is isolated on the far right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372648/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Various issues with the new design of the reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372649/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Timestamps on Answers tab should line up between the questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372655/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Remove repeated "revised" heading from Revisions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372656/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Navigation title/subtitle is clickable, but it doesn't link to anything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372659/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Daily bars in the reputation graph touch the top, please add margin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372664/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Remove considerable amount of empty space below the User feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372665/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [The only useful link in the review history is tiny](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372677/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [New order of badges in Recent badges is hard to follow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372680/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [CSS tweaks to fit more posts into Summary tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372689/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Wasted vertical space in reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372691/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Condensed activity summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372706/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Better information density on reputation change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372757) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Link headers in summary to their subpages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372775) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Wrap Answers and Questions on Summary if two columns view is engaged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372788) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Reputation link should point to Reputation tab, not league](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372797) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Remove dangling "unhelpful" flags raised in IMPACT box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372981/) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Remove duplicated bounty number in box title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372988) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [The amount of whitespace on the "All actions" page is extreme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374979) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Voting corrections/reversals for votes on questions only, when you are the one who cast the votes, don't clearly indicate what happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375602) |  |
| [support](/questions/tagged/support) | [Any reason upvote has green background, but downvote/closure only red text, so upvotes stands out more?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372693/) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [support](/questions/tagged/support) (?) | [Reputation summary wastes enormous amounts of space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372627/) |  |
| [support](/questions/tagged/support) | [Is the check mark centered in the circle of the badge congratulations message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375225) |  |

#### Notes

- Anybody is welcome to contribute to this post; it's a Community wiki after all.
- Sorting order: [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) > [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) > [support](/questions/tagged/support), then [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) > [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) > [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) >  [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) > [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) > no status tag.
- Comments can be used to discuss the structure of this post, e.g. whether the sort order above makes sense or needs to be improved.
- I haven't included some of the (mainly pre-launch) posts yet, mainly because they were 'too broad' and I'm not sure they will get a status tag. I'm happy to be proven wrong!
- On a similar note, posts which pertain to something else than the Activity tab ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372615/)) are not included either.

#### Credits

Original idea: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396655/), further refined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369148/).

Comment: What's going on with the edit history here? https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpfFg.png

Comment: @Camilo can't reproduce it, but you could check whether that bug is already reported elsewhere on Meta.SE and if not, create a new [tag:bug] with some details (OS version, browser version, device).

Comment: @Camilo It could be this ancient bug report: [Revision diff columns overflowing](/q/142420/289905). This happens when there’s a lot of whitespace removed and it seems to be the same cause as [Comment Overflow?](/q/361250/289905). I can only reproduce this in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Comment: @SebastianSimon It does seem to be the same as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142420/revision-diff-columns-overflowing. I can repro on Chrome latest on Windows but not on Edge latest.

Answer (score 141):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

### The padding in the Summary is still enormous

And the font size is still larger than it needs to be.

[image: Summary page after applying “compact” styling]

I still can only see 1 section. That means the old page was still 4× as useful, which means this improvement didn’t actually add any value until you start scrolling. Seeing that there is another header doesn’t do a whole lot for me when I can’t see anything under it.

The font size is 15% larger than regular text; don’t see why it should be. The padding is still very large, both around list items and also between sections.

Update: now that we have side-by-side sections—which I’d honestly not dared to request—problems are considerably lessened. Still, before scrolling I see 2 sections—with the changes suggested below, it could easily be ~3.6, and probably could get all 4 by messing with the space between sections (which I didn’t in that mock-up). As noted in several comments, we can do *even better* by ditching the unnecessary borders and such altogether...

---

(Partially) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed):

### The font size and padding in the lists for the Summary are enormous

This is what I can see of the “sections” below the “summary widget.” The black bar on the bottom is my OS taskbar.

[image: Summary view from Answers down to the bottom of my viewport]

The font size for the hyperlinks is very nearly the same size as for the `h3` header above it for “Answers.” To make matters worse, there’s a gigantic amount of padding around it. On my screen, you can’t even see your Questions from the top of that page, because the 5 Answers already fill it up. In contrast, with the old layout, I could see 4 of the sections in full. That to me literally means **the old page was 4× as useful**.

These literally do not need any padding, at all. They look fine with none. The cutesy little vote box gets a little tight, but distributing their 6px of bottom margin to 2px above and 4px below solves that. The font size could trivially remain normal size rather than over 40% larger. Then at least you get 1.8 sections instead of just 1. Which is still bad, but much less bad.

[image: Altered Summary page with no padding and normal font size]

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, [the padding is _huge_ atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOBmW.png), on pretty much every page with the new table view.

Comment: Ditto for the reputation page. Huge font, huge padding, tiny information.

Comment: @miken32 It's especially bad once you start drilling down, then you've got [padding within padding within padding](https://imgur.com/a/SFnNuEG).  I really liked the ability to see multiple days of reputation at once, and the ability to drill down and still see a concise summary of the data.

Comment: Yes, the font sizes on the Activity tab are killing me. I cannot read that page. Top Questions on the Profile tab are way better. The whole Profile Tab is better.

Comment: I just checked, **twice** if I was zoomed in to 150% while looking at the Summary tab. 19px for a 1080p screen is far too big! It looked like everything was a title

Comment: I don't understand why most of the sites today throw these huge designs in our faces... For people having some difficulties seeing the old design there is an option in any browser called "page scale" (which can be applied per site in some good browsers). The CSS can also differentiate between device types and show different layouts to them. There's absolutely no need to ruin desktop users' experience in favor of mobile ones...

Comment: I actually hit `Ctrl-0` to try and reset scaling, which I assumed I had messed up with a finger fumble at some point.

Comment: This has been mitigated a bit by switching to the same compact layout from the profile page. More to come 

Comment: @AaronShekey I’ll be honest, I would not apply “completed” to this work. My complaints remain almost exactly the same—now I can see the Questions header, but absolutely nothing under it (the tail on the Q even gets cut off a little), which means that the page remains exactly as woefully value-sparse as it was when I posted. More to come, you say—perhaps “pending” would be the more appropriate tag, then.

Comment: @AaronShekey It seems this reduced the enormous font size, but all the excessive padding is still in place.

Comment: The real question is: do we really need a table for questions, answers and tags? The container around is enough.

Comment: @pinckerman Indeed, the root of the problem is that each line is put in a box of its own for no good reason. The layout could be made much tighter if these dividing lines were discarded.

Comment: @AaronShekey What "compact layout" are you talking about? I can't find anything like that option on the profile page.

Comment: @IvanShatsky My understanding was that it was an option for them, as the designers/developers of the page, for how they want the component to display. That toggle isn’t exposed to any user-facing control. Also, the current form _is_ the “compact” version—the non-compact version was the one shown in the middle image of my answer, with the giant font size.

Answer (score 121):

*Author's note:* This critique was posted prior to the go-live of the redesign, and references screenshots from the mock-up video rather than the released layout.

---

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

I really like the improved responsiveness, and I think you've nailed the layout for small screens! My main critique is just that the "summary" page now has *way* too much detail on it – it's too information-rich to be a summary anymore.

For its faults, I feel that the current summary page does what it says on the tin pretty well overall: it provides a "summary" of a user's content – the "30,000 foot view". It's not super detailed, but it shows a lot of key metrics: recent posts and their scores, recent reputation bumps, tag contributions, bookmarks, and vote totals, among a few others.

The new view, on the other hand, kind of throws "summary" out the window – so much detail has been crammed into this one page that it's as tall as a skyscraper, and getting a broad overview from it no longer seems feasible.

I took some screenshots of your video to illustrate what I mean. Here's the current layout:

[image: Current user profile activity summary page layout]Even scrolled to the top, we can see four full sections, and the edge of #5 and 6. From this one single view, I can see answers, questions, posts associated with positive reputation changes, and a user's top tags. I'm also only a short scroll away from the rest (note the length of that scrollbar).

In contrast, here's what we can see on the same screen size in the new layout:

[image: New user profile activity summary page layout]

We can see... *just answers*. Instead of those 9-10 summary sections being a quick scroll away, I'd have to scroll for *miles* to see anything other than the first section. We can't even see the full answers section all at once here.

In my opinion, sections of this detail should really live under their respective tabs instead of the summary page. I would really love to see this much detail for answers under the answer tab!! This new layout is way more useful than what the answers tab [currently provides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQJ2r.png). Ditto for questions and the other dedicated tabs likewise.

A final note I'd add to this is that, while I think this single-column layout looks really great on smaller screens, I don't think it'll look quite as good on larger, desktop-sized ones (which, personally, is how I browse Stack Exchange 99% of the time). Something the current two-column design does well is spread out the information laterally, and reduce the need to scroll, which is something I think this new layout could really benefit from.

Regardless of the final product, thank you for releasing a mock up a week or so early, and leaving the door open for comments. The better communication is greatly appreciated and hopefully will lead to an even better product too!

Comment: Couldn't agree more. We don't need all that information on the summary tab. We need to be able to evaluate several things about the user's activity by looking at _one_ screen.

Comment: Yup, we should just go back to titles only for posts and answers here.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful feedback! I'm inclined to agree that we've strayed too much from a summary view. This view is the product of prioritizing building a responsive layout over making the decisions of what information should and shouldn't be shown. This issue seems most apparent with the "Answers" section, where it's furthest from a summary. We'll be reconsidering how to strike the balance between this view being detailed and being easy to digest.

Comment: @DanCormier Except you're using a perfectly private meaning of "responsive". I want to see a profile, that's the highlights, the skyline, the, you know, *profile* of what a user's up to, and asking for the profile used to be responsive: it showed me that. Now it's *not* responsive. Seriously, trying to hijack characterizations? Stop..

Comment: @jthill No malice or deception intended. I'm using responsive in the sense of "responsive web design" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: @DanCormier I didn't think, and I'm sorry I left that as a reasonable read, you'd come up with the notion yourself. But that's a beautiful example of what I meant by hijacking characterization. "A responsive design adapts the web-page layout to the viewing environment", and rather than adapting the web page layout to the viewing environment, you've adapted the web page layout to a mobile phone display regardless  of what anyone's actually using. It's the opposite of responsive.

Comment: Capital-R Responsive design is often not actually responsive in much the same way that capital-A Agile is often not actually agile.

Answer (score 117):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Tag view has become unusable. I can only see 6 tags at a time (in 1920x1080). **I see more empty unused space than information.** When I'm done scrolling I can't remember what I was looking at just one screen ago.

##### Please make the information more compact visually by removing useless empty margins.

#### It's said horizontal eye movement is the most tiring. I have to move my eyes across the whole screen to see 1 single tag score. This is unsustainable.

###### The announced

> Horizontal navigation turns vertical

###### Turns out to be a lot more horizontal than was said. (To the detriment of the users eye sight health.)

[image]

Comment: +1, there's also way too much horizontal white space imho

Comment: @pinckerman it's said horizontal eye movement is the most tiring. I have to move my eyes across the whole screen to see 1 single tag score. This is unsustainable.

Comment: +1 "I see more empty unused space then information" good summary indeed, that's ridiculous.

Comment: FYI, feature request: [Display density: how about a compact view?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229898/178179)

Comment: +1 Back to showing at least 40 tags per screen, please.

Answer (score 111):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

The new reputation page is, in my opinion, the worst of the changes, and [it seems like I'm not alone](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53606945#53606945).

As [others have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372649#comment1244300_372606) [pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372627/1091571), it wastes a **very large** amount of space. Before this change, it was very compact. Each rep change had its own small line, and it was a piece of cake to see the rep changes for the whole day.

One problem with the "multi-line" view of each rep change is that for users that have a lot of rep changes in one day, *for many posts*, the usability of the reputation page is severely degraded. Consider [Jon Skeet's page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation), and expand a day there. There are *a lot* of different posts, and since each one takes up a lot of space, it's a total pain to look through them, especially having to scroll several page-lengths (even on my large screen) to overview them all.

Now try that on a more active day, such as [February 29, 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=71). There he had over 108 upvotes, each on a different post.

As [@Dharman said](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53606904#53606904), this makes it 100x harder to check for issues like voting fraud.

The new design keeps making me think the sun is shining on my screen — I keep shifting this way and that in an effort to evade the ugliness of the view, but I'm stuck with it.

---

There's a bug, where you can only see the *time* of a rep change event IF *multiple* rep changes occurred for that post. If only one change happens for that post, which is most common, e.g., an upvote, you can only see the day, and **not** the time.

On this post, I got multiple changes, so I can see the time that they occurred:

[image]

On this post, since I only got one event (an upvote), I can see only the day it occurred, but not the time:

[image]

Comment: You can't see the time for changes that happened yesterday at all. It just says x hours ago

Comment: The reputation page is either extremely buggy by 1. Not showing the time and thereby grouping things into "3 hour ago" or 2. Its design needs to be completely reworked. It drops down on the wrong elements. Doesn't come back when asking the drop down to do back up and it outright refuses to give me a breakdown of for example two downvotes despite the fact that there's a little arrow on that, but it expands a completely different element! :O

Comment: It needs needs to be completely redone. It's the worst part of the UI right now. I'm not trying to be harsh, but I'm just exasperated by the fact that such a perfect UI in almost everyway has been changed in this manner.

Comment: ^ what the above comment says, but for the whole page...

Comment: @EvgenKo423 I certainly prefer the compactness and optimization of space (the two columns especially) of the old page, but I have to admit I'm partial toward the clean, modern feel of the new components. The padding, of course, is a no-go. I think these people are throwing the baby (the usability, and therefore the desktop users) out with the bath water (the unresponsive design).

Comment: Though I like the UI components' look and file, I very seriously doubt that that look and feel needs to come to the reputation page. If it's going to, it had **better not** mess up the _ease_ of usage of that page.

Answer (score 107):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

### Why does the Reputation summary waste such enormous amounts of space?

Reputation used to default to having recent days expanded, but individual Questions/Answers in the list collapsed. This was the correct default state—which is to say, the current implementation that defaults to everything collapsed is the *wrong* default state.

And why is everything collapsed? Because everything takes up **enormous amounts of space**. Each Q or A is three lines long for absolutely no reason, the font size on the title/link is gigantic, and then there’s tons of padding on everything.

This is a simple list. It should be rendered as a list. All these boxes and padding and everything are not only unnecessary, **they completely destroy any value or usefulness that the page may have had**.

I would sooner recommend removing the page altogether—and eliminating the annoying blue dot indicating that the page has something of value to show me—than leave it in this state.

Comment: Because the spaces goes away on mobile, the view the design was designed for.

Comment: PLEASE, do something about whitespaces on the reputation page. It looks a little bit nasty at the moment. There's so much whitespace and it requires more scrolling. The button to expand is proportionally too small. And the difference between "time" and "post" view is really strange. Why have two different table designs for the same thing? Please unify it and remove the whitespace.

Comment: As I said in an above comment, once you drill down, you have [padding within padding within padding](https://imgur.com/a/SFnNuEG).

Comment: And why is everything forced to start out collapsed?  This takes **more clicks to see less**, particularly on a larger desktop screen.  To sum it up, you've now made it **less efficient and less enjoyable to spend my time on Stackoverflow**.  One of my most visited pages is far, far less usable now.  I can't find ANY improvements in the current design such that simply reverting back to what you had is the best recommendation I have.

Answer (score 87):

## Instead of useful features, layout update contained bobcat.  Would not buy again.

---

### The activity page used to look like this

[image: good ol' summary pane]

Note the efficient use of space, with nothing squished into an overly-tiny space or stretched out to fill an overly-big space.  Note the ability to switch between the summary/answers/questions/tags/badges/bookmarks/following/bounties/reputation/all-actions/responses/votes panes from at or near the top of the page, without having to scroll up and down to see the whole switching menu.

[image: this is neat, useful, and compact]

Note the lightweight question/repchange/answer markers, showing where your highly-regarded questions and answers are and where you've been gaining or losing reputation lately, without cluttering up the page with information that can easily be had by following the provided links.  Note how this allows lots of information to be compactly summarized in the summary tab without taking up an inordinate amount of space.

---

### Now it looks like this

[image: you've managed to create horizontal congestion on a wide screen; nice job, genius]

Note how the three boxes of the summary segment of the summary pane have been squished into a space too small for them to comfortably fit.  Note how the switching menu, now that it runs vertically down the side of the page in the column freed up by crushing the summary pane, runs off the bottom of the screen, necessitating scrolling down to see the whole thing.  Note the oddity of putting *more* things side-by-side, producing cramping issues that will be even more severe on narrower screens, when the intent of the design changes is ostensibly to make the desktop site *more* mobile-(and-thus-narrower-screen-)friendly.  Note also how the blue square on the bookmarks tab (and presumably the other tabs of the pane switcher) is now a smaller circle that crowds the edges of the number inside it and makes it harder to read.

[image: where has everything gone]

[image: these are much too big]

Note how the segments of the summary pane have grown ridiculously huge in order to ensure that there will only be room for a single column of said segments.  Note the enormously-increased amount of scrolling that simply scanning the summary pane for some information found in one of the later segments now entails.

[image: we haven't even scrolled halfway down the page yet]

Note how the tags segment, in particular, now consists of a single column of tags on the left, some tag stats on the right, and a huge block of empty space in between.  Note how, in addition to this, the individual tag entries have been blown up to match the size of the question and answer and repchange and whatnot entries - specifically, to match their *new*, inflated size.  Note how, as a result, the tags segment now takes much more space to convey a little more than *half* as much information as it used to.

[image: vacant white column, for sale by owner]

Note how, due to the use of a sidebar to house the pane-switcher menu, we now have a whole column of blank space over on the left which does nothing but shove the segments of the summary pane over to the right, leaving them with too little remaining screen width to comfortably accommodate a second column of segments, yet still far more than needed for a single column.  Note that width restrictions on mobile devices could have been better accommodated by leaving the pane switcher as it was before (thus freeing up precious screen width for the segments themselves), and dynamically shuffling the segments from two columns into one on screens too narrow to comfortably accommodate two side-by-side columns of segments, *without* ruining the page for desktop users whose screens could easily accommodate two columns side-by-side.

[image: reputation chart breaketh]

Note that, presumably as (yet another) bad effect of blowing everything up to hugeness, the repchange bar chart is now borked.  Note, firstly, that the individual bars are now crammed tightly against each other *despite* having more room to spread out; without the thin whitespace that formerly separated adjacent bars in the chart, bars of the same or similar height next to one another could potentially merge in the viewer's eye, causing confusion.  Note, secondly, that the taller bars are now whacking their heads on the gray border at the top of (and also surrounding) the segment in question.

---

**Summary: 0/10, would not buy again.  (Boo!!!  Hiss!!!)**

System: Chrome 96 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86-64.

---

### Update

Sometime in the past 20 hours, the layout changed slightly.  Now the Questions and Answers segments are narrower and side-by-side, somewhat reducing the amount of scrolling needed, and it looks like some of the other elements may have been shrunken slightly as well.  However, even at their smaller size, they're still bigger than they need to be; other segments desperately in need of side-by-sideness (tags, for instance) are still single-file; there are still unnecessary gray borders around everything that do nothing but take up space; and the new question-/answer-segment side-by-sideness further highlights the problems with the vertical pane switcher, as the width it takes up, and the resultant reduction in screen width usable by the segments next to it, causes the question titles in the question and answer segments to be cut off short enough to often make it impossible to figure out at a glance just *what* the question is.  (Not helping matters is the completely-unnecessary question-date label at the far-right end of each of the question/answer bars.  The date of a question I asked is easily found by going to its question page; the date of a question that I answered is completely irrelevant for my purposes, since what we're interested in here is the *answer* I wrote to the question; and, in both cases, it forces the question name to be cut off earlier than otherwise.)

[image: half measures satisfy no one]

---

**New summary: maybe 1-2/10.  Still awful.**

---

### Further update

Things have marginally improved, with the tag and reputation segments now also supporting two-column viewing; the narrowing from going back into two columns also seems to have incidentally unborked the reputation graph, which looks to be back to its old self:

[image: at least the reputation chart is fixed]

Note, additionally, how the question titles in the reputation segment now wrap instead of cutting off, which is a nice feature.

#### However!

- The tags segment still has far fewer tags visible than it used to, and, thus, manages to still contain considerable whitespace despite its much-decreased width.
- The space-wasting gray borders which force the entries in each segment further apart are still there; removing those borders would *easily* free up enough space to enable the question titles in the question and answer segments to wrap (as has now been done for the reputation segment), rather than being cut off.
- The side-mounted pane switcher is still taking up precious screen width and making an entire (fairly-substantial!) column of the screen unusable by anything else.  Just look at the huge vertical white bar on the left side of the screen:

[image: white column, still vacant]

- The side-mounted pane switcher *also* still requires vertical scrolling to reach its lowermost items on most screens.  Although you said that you implemented the vertical pane switcher to avoid the need for wrapping the pane switcher if more panes are added to it in future, the cure is far worse than the problem; keeping the previous, horizontal, pane switcher and allowing it to wrap around onto two or more rows would have taken up a marginal amount of additional vertical room, while (unlike the vertical pane switcher) *not* requiring scrolling to see the whole switcher or crushing the rest of the page laterally.
- The remaining segments of the summary pane (bookmarks, followed posts, accounts, bounties, and votes cast) are still single-file-only, and thus still horrendously space-wastey on wide screens:

[image: c'mon, this could easily fit in two columns]

[image: stop wasting space, dammit]

- The new graphics in the badges segment are gorgeous... *and belong on the badges pane, not the summary pane!*  A simple list of my latest few badges would be sufficient for the badges segment of the summary pane, while the badges pane would benefit enormously from the gold/silver/bronze graphics currently found in the summary pane.  As a matter of fact, I'm not sure that the summary pane even needs the badges segment *at all*, given that there is, and has always been, a display of my total gold/silver/bronze badges *right at the top of the summary pane*, including both my newest badge and the one I'm closest to earning next!

[image: it's beautiful, but this isn't where it should be]

[image: you couldn't've put it here instead?]

- And, even with the reputation events from more than a few days ago now being collapsed by default (like they used to be), the reputation pane is *still* horribly space-wastey - I'd like to be able to see more than just my past three or four reputation events *without* having to shell out 10 grand for an 8K monitor, peeps!

[image: is someone getting paid by the pixel here?]

---

**Current assessment?  Maybe 3/10, would still not buy again.**

---

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### My recommendations at this point?  Honestly, I'd say the best option would be to revert the layout update completely and go back to what the layout was on 6 December, except with the addition of summary-pane dynamic segment columning (segments automatically reshuffle into two columns on wide screens, and one column on narrow ones) and summary-pane question-title wrapping (question titles wrap instead of cutting off, like what the reputation segment currently does), as well as the ability to wrap the horizontal pane-switcher (if that hadn't already been implemented).  *EVERYTHING ELSE about the new layout is a net negative, ESPECIALLY for desktop users, and needs to go ASAP.*

---

Note: I am aware of the irony of me complaining about (among other things) the need for a vastly-increased amount of scrolling... in an answer which requires a great deal of scrolling. :-p  Nevertheless, I judged the multitude of screenshots to be necessary for illustrating the points made in my answer, *unlike* the necessary-for-absolutely-nothing whitespace and padding and added borders and single-columning added by the layout update.

Comment: I’d note that _even on mobile_, I preferred the old layout. Sure, everything was zoomed out, which wasn’t great, but zooming in on whatever interested me was easy enough. Navigating a drop-down menu, expanding list items, etc. are much more painful than that.

Comment: I regret that I have but one upvote to give.

Comment: A bobcat would've been preferable, honestly.

Comment: What’s wrong with bobcats?

Comment: Just for those who don’t know, the “bobcat” thing is a reference to [XKCD #325](//xkcd.com/325).

Comment: Note that the page is limited to a width of 1100 pixels. If you're logged out, the summary is always single-column. If you're logged in, your window needs to be wider than 1100 pixels (more if you have the left navigation on) for double columns, even though they look fine to me at a simulated width of 1000 pixels. Also annoyingly, only four areas are supported in double columns anyway.

Comment: @Neil: "Note that the page is limited to a width of 1100 pixels" - well, that's dumb, given that probably the vast majority of users have screens considerably wider than that and could comfortably accommodate a greater page width.

Comment: Seems the date listing is now the answer date for answers.  (When sorting by "activity", it's still the date of the answer's original posting.  That might actually be a good choice, though.)

Answer (score 66):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> No functionality has been lost ...

Here is what the "Votes cast" section on the summary page looked like before the change:

[image: "Votes cast" summary section before]

However, here is what that looks like now:

[image: "Votes cast" summary section after]

One could "technically" determine the votes cast during the past month, week and day by manually counting from the overall list of up and down votes, but I consider this to effectively be functionality that has been removed.

Note I have sometimes found that extra summary information useful for myself, such as when I check how many votes I still have available for the day. Also, as [Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-anonymous-hedgehog)'s [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372624?noredirect=1#comment1244314_372624) states, this information helped to determine and report a user for vote invalidation because they had [upvoted every question on a site to earn a gold badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269082/spam-voting-should-we-stop-it).

Comment: It's useful as an indication of activity, which... seems relevant given this is the activity tag

Comment: This is a terrible loss. I looked at this thing every day for myself, and often for other users. **PLEASE** bring it back.

Comment: Ah, but it still looks terrible... It needs information density back.

Comment: I really wonder whether this was just oversight or someone thinking, "eh, who care about these numbers anyway?"

Answer (score 60):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Not
Every
Element
Needs
Its
Own
Line

Others have talked about the whitespace in general, but I wanted to touch on one specific part: putting multiple things on the same line when they fit.  Some pages handle this quite well; for example, the Following page has the tags and the date on the same line:
[image: A post with the tags and the date on the same line]
...unless it gets too narrow, in which case the date drops down to the next line:
[image: A post with the date on the line below the tags]

This is great!  However, many other pages unconditionally put elements on their own line, resulting in wasted vertical space and weirdly empty aesthetics.  Part of being *responsive* is making good use of space on *wider* displays as well, and these just aren't.

For example, the close votes page:
[image: First line: "closure", second line: "Some off-topic question [closed]", third line: "39m"]

The votes pages:
[image: First line: "upvote", second line: "A great post", third line: "Dec 2"]

Various parts of the reputation page:
[image: First line: "+20 2 events", second line: the post name, third line: "Oct 29"]
[image: "+10" and "Upvote" over top of each other, with "Oct 29 at 19:43" centered vertically to the right]

In all of these cases, these elements could *easily* fit on one line on a desktop-sized display.  Consider having them on one line for larger screens, and then break onto multiple lines for smaller displays.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372699/361484

Answer (score 53):

I can only see downsides to this:

> The navigation includes all the same items but is now placed vertically to the left of the column of sections to fix moments like this.

1. In any normal sized screen (the kind developers actually work on) all the tabs fit in 1 single line, you just created an entire column (and the empty space beneath it) for what is 1 line.

> It’ll allow us to add more functionality in the future without breaking the layout or introducing any wrapping.

2. Creating a column to prevent hypothetical future wrapping of a line of tabs (because of tabs that don't yet exist - and haven't changed in a long time) doesn't seem like a good argument.

> Two columns become one

3. As zcoop98 said, I like my information at a glance, this only creates problems by compartmentalizing info that should be kept grouped. How many times do we have to click in the new layout to get an overview of activity? Instead of 1 click and 1 short scroll, we now need 10 clicks and 10 long scrolls.

> Summary stays on “Summary”

4. This is where I think the design goes seriously wrong. **The expanded post summaries should not clutter the activity tab of the user profile.** When checking a user profile I'm not interested in that kind of detail, and if I am I'll use search. This choice seems like a substitute for:

- Having somewhere to click if you want that kind of detail.
- Actually using [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=)
- Having a possibility to see expanded details in [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+user%3A1)

**P.S.**

> Horizontal navigation turns vertical

When was navigation ever horizontal?

Comment: I actually like the vertical navigation. As said in the video, it “scans better”. And I really feel like I can read the navigation items quicker and click them easier.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! For point 4, we agree. I’ve heard from a few people that the page strays a bit from feeling like a summary and this view could use tightening. On point 3, can you clear up what you mean by needing 10 clicks to get an overview of activity? The need to scroll is increased, but I'm not sure about clicking. For 1, 2, and PS, I want to make sure I don’t assume the screen or browser width a given developer (or any user) will use. I think the vertical nav is easier to use and worth the extra empty space created, but I’ll bring this up to my team and open it up for debate.

Comment: @DanCormier by 10 clicks I mean the new column that replaces the tabs. Formerly the summary worked fine, now you either click or have to scroll endlessly. I'm not the first one to say that [UX for typical 1920x1080 laptop users is degrading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361393).

Comment: Agree with points 2 & 3, adding a column for "nav" that doesn't occupy the entire column's space is a waste. I'd much rather waste part of a row of screen real estate for content often scrolled off-screen than waste a column of on-screen real estate permanently. It's also actually still 2 columns, the first was traded for the vertical nav/tabs and would be mostly useless now.

Comment: It is so frustrating how long it takes me to get from A to B.

Answer (score 51):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

> Everything that's on [the new] page includes everything on [the old] page. Right. We didn't lose any data. We didn't hide anything. We actually have additional information, like this answer and some of this data here. So it's just organised in a little bit of a different way.

[2:50-3:10 of the video](https://youtu.be/1hPjjvp4b8I?t=170)

I want to challenge the *losing* of data. The page is now so overloaded with information that looking for *an overview* of a user's activity is now instead a detailed look into what the user did recently. Yes, that is not "hiding" or "losing" data. However, to stretch a metaphor a bit - it has dumped a haystack on top of a needle.

The information about the tags of a post, the little snippet and similar are useful if I want to see them. If I instead want to see at a glance *has* the user posted questions and/or answers I now have to scroll what seems from the video at least two screens. The answer section definitely took up one screen:

[image: Screenshot of the video where the page is filled with only answer information and has to be scrolled further up or down to even see the beginning or end of the section]

Notice that the buttons for sorting these are still on top. Right now, the answers are sorted by votes - what if I scroll all the way down and realise I actually wanted the newest ones? I have to *scroll back* again just to switch the ordering, so I can go *scroll down* again. And maybe I find out I still do not see the information I want, so I have to *scroll up* again to click and view all answers.

Comment: I'm pretty much in agreement that the summary view can be tightened up by being more selective about the information we choose to show. The answer section is the best illustration of this. I think showing a snippet of the answer is nice and relevant, but we can probably stand to lose some of the other info shown the better condense and emphasize the what's most important. Thanks for sharing your thoughts. There's tons of room for improvement and your feedback helps us know where to best spend our efforts.

Comment: Also there is so much space - lets please go back to two columns so we can see more instead of all the information we have lost - A summary page should not require scrolling

Comment: @DanCormier I would even challenge that an answer snippet is not too useful. First off, a minor redundancy is that the question title and the "View answer" button are identical links. The snippet also breaks Mathjax blocks (e.g. on Math.SE), and are hard to read when it opens with code (e.g. on SO). More to the point, I don't think most answers are (or even can be) summarized in the first couple of sentences, so the utility is limited.

Comment: @DanCormier Fundamentally, I feel it's hard for a reader to skim the first couple of sentences from a dozen answers and get a feel for the quality or style of a user's contributions, so I'm not sure if it really belongs on a summary page.

Comment: @DanCormier Also I realize this answer is for the answer section of the summary tab, which is now much more condensed, but what I want to advocate for is a more condensed answer tab as well. I could move these comments to a separate answer, if that would make it easier for the purposes of keeping track of feature requests.

Answer (score 46):

## Wasted vertical space

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

This is a **lot** of wasted vertical space in the reputation history for what used to be a nice compact list conveying useful information at a glance. Please tighten it up again. (Ah, looks like that was [raised elsewhere as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372649/134069).)

[image]

Answer (score 40):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Add back the numbers indicating how much reputation changed or how many responses were received on the tabs

When there's a reputation change or new responses received, earlier, the tab would indicate a number as to how much my reputation changed or how many new responses were received since I last loaded the respective tab.

However, this now seems to be gone, with it only showing a dot, but no number:

[image: Dot, no number]

Can the number of responses or amount of change in reputation please be added back?

I found these numbers really useful. As an example, when changes are made to my posts that don't trigger a notification (e.g. tag-only edits or really minor text edits), the system doesn't notify me of those, but those *do* show up as new Responses. I don't usually pay attention to that tab since I'm generally notified of all other activity, so it tends to stay with pending new responses for a long time. However, if I load up my profile and see that I suddenly have a lot of new responses that I didn't have earlier and wasn't notified of, I can see that mass changes were made to my posts, which I can report if they were improper. It's now harder to see that now, though, since I can't see the number anymore.

A similar thing also applies to reputation changes: users aren't notified of negative changes, but those (generally) do show up in the tab header. If I see a negative change, I'm implicitly prompted to see which of my posts were downvoted or what happened. However, it's now harder to see.

Also, to quote from my [previous answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372599/377214):

> > No functionality has been lost
>
> Pedantically speaking, that's not quite true.

The functionality to easily see your changes in reputation and responses, including those you're not notified about, has been lost.

Comment: This is definitely accidental lost functionality. It's coming back. Thanks for the bug report!

Comment: Crap! that blue circle is the worst, looks like some terminator and a brand color had a baby, eeek. Now it shows the number but shit. 5/0

Answer (score 38):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Deleted answers used to show up in red (at least for moderators). They don't anymore, neither on the Summary tab:

[image]

nor on the Answers tab:

[image]

This used to be very useful, at least for me, to see whether a user is a repeat spammer, or somebody with just one deleted post and reasonable other contributions to the site. The red background *is* still shown on e.g. Questions and the Delete votes tab:

[image]

[image]

([test user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/504454/waied-anes-abduiaziz-al-areqi?tab=answers))

Comment: They showed up in red for normal users too

Comment: Indeed as @TylerH says; now they show up in red only in the respective tabs (Bookmarks & Followed posts), but not in Summary.

Comment: Dug into this one and deleted stuff _should_ be highlighting as red. Sorry for the delay!

Comment: @AaronShekey great, I've fixed my Destroy Spammer user script for moderators which relied on that highlight being present. Thank you!

Comment: @AaronShekey they still *don't*, under several tabs (at least Reputation, Bookmarks, Following).

Answer (score 35):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The "Answers" section of the summary is showing the score and acceptance state of the **questions** I answered, not the score and acceptance state of my answers. It appears to still sort by my answer score, activity and creation date appropriately though.

[image: Screenshot of the answers section of the author's profile sorted by votes that shows the votes don't match the order of the sort]

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. This one is... weird. Looking into it now.

Comment: @BenKelly The scores seem to be fixed, but the acceptance states are still checking the question to see if it has any accepted answer, not if the answer itself is accepted.

Comment: Just a tickle, but the acceptance states are still showing whether the question has an accepted answer, not whether the answer is accepted (I know this is still status-planned). Thanks for fixing the scores quickly!

Comment: Thanks for the update folks! I have a fix in PR that should be out today-ish. I'll update the status on this after it goes live. Sorry for the wait, there's a bit of a rush internally that leads up to our holiday code freeze and this dropped off my radar.

Answer (score 34):

This change drastically reduces the usability of this page for my most common actions. It's impossible to get a quick overview now, or to scan lots of information quickly. Everything takes up a huge amount of space, the information densitity is very low. It feels like standing directly in front of a huge screen, there is no way for me to get any overview.

It's bad enough for my use cases as a regular user, but as a mod if I needed to look into a user for patterns of problematic behaviour, I might just give up now. I really need high information density for that use case as I need to quickly scan the user activity. There is no quick scanning with this page, there's just lots and lots of scrolling.

Some parts are also hard to scan for me due to the layout, e.g. the question and answer lists. I generally need the title, the score and the deletion status for this, all the other stuff around it now makes it harder to focus on the important parts.

The list of accounts is also very useful information for me as a moderator, it tells me something about what kind of user this is. Now I either need to scroll down several pages worth until I see that or go to the profile page.

Answer (score 33):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The redesign looks weird on bigger screens. The profile tab gives much strain to eyes. Here is the new design vs the old design on my 21:9 monitor.

#### New design

[image]

#### Old design

[image]

The fonts are tooooooo big..

## way bigger than the stackoverflow logo..

[image]

## sorry for visual disturbance, To illustrate what it feels like, is using `h1`s instead of `p`.

Also the top tags and reputation chart needs some refinement
[image]
[image]

Comment: [tag:status-review] means a developer is looking into it; **not** 'please review this issue'.

Comment: Here is [my post about the tags issue on a Profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371231/578924) which was declined.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for pointing out, I didn't knew this. First time in meta, just for my eye strain's sake. just curious how meta works.. never knew mods edit posts and add tag.

Comment: Well, it's basically the same for me. I think you should rather put this into your post instead of a comment and you actually comparing the tags on a Profile page with Activity page which confused me. ;-)

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy sure, happy to educate you. We do know Meta is different :) Thanks for posting this bug report!

Answer (score 32):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

### Poor information architecture on the Answers page

#### (or: my answers do not have answers)

The *most* prominently highlighted piece of information in each answer's box on a user's Answers page, with a bright green box in the top left is...the total number of answers on the question that it is answering, and whether any of them are accepted.  The *least* prominently highlighted piece of information, buried in the middle in light gray text, is the answer's score.

This seems almost exactly backwards: the score is quite possibly one of the *most* important things about an answer, and the number of answers on the question and their accepted status (note: *not* the accepted status of the answer—only one of the two answers in this screenshot is accepted) is surely the least important thing about an answer: who cares how many other answers there are?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reporting it.  [This was already reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372652#372652)

Comment: @Vanny Thanks for the reply, but I'm reporting a very different issue than that.  That answer just says that "score" should be used instead of "votes."  This is about the structure of the answer item: specifically the focus on the **question's** metadata rather than the answer's score.  This asks for more than a wording change, it asks to put the emphasis on the answer's score.  Please reconsider whether this is actually a duplicate of that answer.

Comment: Was about to post the same answer. This is unbearable. It's almost impossible to understand what is going on in the answers page at a glance. Content is irregularly splattered all over the place. The scores of the answers is barely visible in grey, and it's hidden in one hundred rows of overtly formatted and superfluous information. Also, scores higher than 1000 show as 1k/2k etc instead of the exact count, which is annoying. Please @Vanny consider highlighting votes, using full counts and removing unneeded info.

Comment: For reference, I'd keep the answers/questions page similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJXhc.png (with full vote counts) and maybe add a button/checkbox to show extended info.

Answer (score 32):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

<sup>(later also requested in separate bug report: [Don't hide the "closed", "duplicate", or "migrated" state of questions on user question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375495/165773))</sup>

Bring back indication of what questions are closed / duplicates. It was there in prior activity page and it was lost in redesign.

I use this information in my own and others profiles for closing and reopening purposes and its loss makes it harder for me to use the activity page.

As an example, below is a screen shot from [my activity page questions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165773/gnat?tab=questions) here at MSE. Three of six questions marked red are closed (duplicates) but this fact is not displayed anymore.

[image: screen shot from my activity page questions tab]

---

On a further thought, [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368686/165773) from discussion of prior profile changes seems to be relevant here as well:

> ...major flaw in profile redesign:
>
> > **I can’t run every change by the Community ahead of time**
>
> Above is what makes things unreliable and unnecessarily difficult. Sorry if this may sound like a broken record but I would want to repeat advice from previous post on that matter: make it possible to [deploy profile changes to one of (part of) sites in the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368312/165773).
>
> This would let you have it tested as thoroughly as it gets. Also, this would make things inherently safe: whatever bug occasionally slips into production, you would be able to easily roll it back if needed by a simple flip of the switch, by turning new profile off at the affected site(s)...

Comment: strongly related: [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168) "I would want that questions with 10 or more answers... have additional UI allowing me to review each of previous answers individually prior to posting my own... at this point it becomes _way too cumbersome_ to check prior answers in regular UI." To say that checking prior 90 (that's friggin' ni-ne-ty) answers here was PITA would be a severe understatement

Comment: Yes, those status indicators in the titles convey essential information about the posts.

Comment: please bring the indicator back also for bookmarks/followed posts

Comment: It could even be an icon or an additional word next to the answer/votes/views data. But it needs to be **something.**

Comment: @Vanny - I just re-checked my profile page and page of some askers at SO and this issue appears to be addressed, I can see the `[closed]` and `[duplicate]` indications. Does that mean [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 31):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can we please get the UTC timestamp back when hovering over the time field in the Reputation tab? Both on the "Post", but especially in the "Time" submenu. Right now there's just the "Oct 7 at 13:22".

[image: Showing the reputation for one post under the "Time" submenu]

It would be nice to have a uniform representation in the DOM for people that creates user scripts. Some of us also like to know the time down to the very second.

I'm also a little confused as to why the -2 appears both in red and in green.

Comment: The timestamp is especially useful when relative time is shown, like "XX hours ago". And speaking of time, I would prefer to see it in my local time zone; it was like that some time before, but was later changed to UTC.

Comment: No, UTC is good as long as the time zone is specified. e.g. `Z`

Comment: @Dharman It's fine in timestamp, but it's quite confusing when you look at some action time. The relative time is actually shown in local time zone, but the absolute time is now in UTC for some reason.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 What does "The relative time is actually shown in local time zone" mean? "5 hours ago" isn't local time. It's just 5 hours ago everywhere.

Comment: @Unconsidered It means if I'll take my local time and subtract X hours I will get the time when the action was actually performed in my timezone, but the server time will be different by timezone offset. I.e. it's relative within my or server timezone, not relative from my to server time (which is shown along older actions).

Answer (score 31):

> No functionality has been lost ...

Here is how a bookmark, of this post actually, now appears:

[image: Current view of a bookmark entry]

Previously, the date/time shown at the bottom right of the bookmark entry was of the last change, not of when the question was posted as is shown now. It also used to show the user (with a hyperlink) who made that change.

Note the date/time entry used to be a hyperlink to the last change. I often found this useful, especially for posts with many answers, so I didn't have to potentially do a lot of checking to find what specifically had been recently changed. However, the date/time shown now in the lower right corner is no longer a hyperlink, and I can't find any other place that has such a link or any other way to determine what the last change was.

Clicking on the three vertical dots at the top right side brings up a menu list with just one entry of "Remove bookmark". If you prefer to not change what is currently showing, including adding/changing any hyperlinks, then I suggest adding a link to the latest change in that menu list instead.

Comment: +1000 if I could. This is how I used to quickly check any change in past questions. Now, it is much more cumbersome.

Comment: You actually could, @VonC, it's called bounty. ;)

Comment: Actually the date used to depend on the tab selected; it was a date added for "Added" tab, for example. Also the "Active" date in question header also link to the last activity, so you could use that as a workaround.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 Nope, it's called two bounties ;-P

Comment: @41686d6564 Wait, what, a rep cap? Such a shame you can't enter a custom amount...

Answer (score 30):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I find that each answer in the new summary is taking up *way* too much space on desktop devices and makes it much harder to get an overview over one's activity than before.

New layout:

[image]

I suggest increasing the information density by hiding the excerpt from the answer and by putting all the meta data on one line. The same three Q&A's shown above could be condensed into:

[image]

<sup>*The black box around the "unaccepted" answer isn't part of the proposal. I'm just bad at editing images.*</sup>

There could be a small "unhide" button, like ▶ or ⊞, first on each topic line to show an excerpt from that specific answer.

Comment: Better yet, go further and remove all of the question answer count, votes, and view: they're not relevant to the answer.

Comment: Happy to reduce the information density here by removing the row of meta data above the question. Gonna try it out!

Comment: @AaronShekey That sounds promising but I felt it necessary to clarify my suggestion so it's now updated.

Comment: I've reduced the amount of meta data on each question. I know it's not the exact thing you mocked up, but we think previewing the answer is important.

Comment: @AaronShekey Great! It's much cleaner now but now I can't see if the question has an accepted answer (unless it's mine). The line showing "Accepted answer" (and the votes for the answer)  has plenty of horizontal space so it could fit in there.  So could the _view answer_ link. Everything to reduce the amount of vertical space each question takes up. Perhaps too many suggestions for a comment? Should I write a proper suggestion for it instead?

Comment: @AaronShekey The "View answer" link is not needed, the question title already links to it. The answer score and acceptance state could be placed to the left of question title in a box, like before.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 They are two different links though. One links to the question and the other to the answer. I would be happy with a link to the answer only if only one had to be shown since it's a link _from_ a list of answers - but, there's plenty of room vertically to display both.

Comment: @TedLyngmo They both link to an answer for me, like before (and I don't want a question link there).

Comment: @EvgenKo423 Indeed. I could have sworn that they were two different links. Yes, then the _View answer_ link could be removed.

Answer (score 29):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The summary page no longer shows scores of answers and questions. It shows vote count and answer count, 2 pieces of information that are not very important. Especially when ordered by score or views.

Please show uniform size boxes with the post score inside them regardless of whether it's an answer or a question. Just a number would be enough. And make the text a little bit bigger inside of it.

[image]

Comment: This is particularly strange when sorting by votes, as you can't actually see the scores.

Comment: Update: now answers show **question**'s vote count. Misleading.

Comment: @dan Thanks for the fix, but the accepted status is still invalid. It shows my answers as accepted but they are not.

Comment: @Dharman We have a fix for what you're mentioning ([related to this response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372716#372716)). I think what's mentioned in your post has been addressed, but if I'm mistaken, let me know.

Answer (score 26):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

While some aspects of new designs can be judged up front, the real issues show only when we are able to see the new design in full.

Based on how awful this new design looks, feels and how much it lacks already established features, before rolling out such drastic changes, you seriously need to consider having a test phase during which people would be able to switch between designs and give you more comprehensive feedback.

The current Activity page with its enormous fonts is completely unreadable for me. I have eyesight issues and adapting from huge to small sizes causes serious strain to my eyes. I cannot go to the Activity page, read something there, and then continue reading other parts of the site or continue to do my work.

So for now I have to avoid the Activity page, which will have negative impact on my participation, while I wait in hope you will fix the problematic areas.

Fixing an airplane in flight is not the best approach ever.

Comment: We worked to ship some design refinements that should hopefully improve things for you. No arguments on fixing an airplane mid-flight, but that's the reality of working on these pages. To put it kindly, we don't have great infrastructure for doing large A/B's and allowing people to opt in.

Comment: @AaronShekey Thanks for the quick fix. I can read Activity page now.

Answer (score 25):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

### Make it clear that most statistics in the Impact box are hyperlinks

When I loaded up my profile, I was confused as to where the link to my flag summary was. After several attempts, I couldn't find it, until I eventually realized that the helpful flags number in the Impact box was a link, not just plain text:

[image: Looks like plain text]

Those labels definitely don't look like links to me. Also, the "people reached" text is not a hyperlink, but the rest of the text labels are, so I don't get why they're all still formatted the same.

Can the fact that those three labels are hyperlinks be made more clear?

Comment: This is [fixed in high contrast mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413401/all-links-are-underlined-in-high-contrast-mode). You will see that [***all*** links are underlined](https://i.imgur.com/PGllDRU.png)

Comment: In the old design the whole line was a link, so **make the numbers part of a link as well**.

Comment: And conversely, things that I'd expect to be links (like the Questions, Answers, Tags, etc.) section titles aren't, but instead have unnecessary, small "View all 97 answers" links below them (which also aren't obviously links). Except that in the mobile version, those section headings *are* links. What's actually lacking, I think, is some sort of discernible visual language that'd help us predict what is or isn't a link.

Answer (score 24):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On the All actions → Posts tab, the answers have a label 'answered' with a white text on a green background. This gives me the idea that they are accepted, even if they are not:

[image]

Comment: IIRC, it was like that before, but I agree.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 I'm not 100% sure, but I found [this old snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20150925040726/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=activity&sort=posts) which seems to suggest it wasn't.

Comment: This one indeed looks like an old snapshot, @Glorfindel. I think it was a recent change sometime in the last two years, as I seem to remember seeing both of them.

Comment: I am not sure if this is actually a bug. But, I think if an answer is accepted, it should show accepted in green instead of answered. But I can see the possible confusion because when it shows as asked, there are no colors, and doesn't show as a tag, just plain text.

Answer (score 22):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Posts edit field has lost precision in the impact section.

I liked seeing how many posts I've edited and comparing that with the number of helpful flags and votes. These are usually around the same order of magnitude but now two fields use 4 digits while edited posts only uses 1 due to rounding.

[image]

Comment: The missing precision is the worst part of this.  Editing a single post can be a nontrivial amount of effort: each one should be visible (at least within reason, but this is well within reason).

Comment: These 3 metrics should never round. They are meant to be precise.

Comment: @DanCormier: After the update, it looks like the number shown is drastically different from what is shown when you click on the 'post edited' link (i.e., the all actions>revisions page). Does the number in the impact section show the number of unique posts edited or is this due to something else? (I seem to remember my edited posts being higher before all the changes).

Comment: @Shaido when you click the "posts edited" link the list shows every revision to your own post and posts of other users. The number above "posts edited" counts only 1 for all the revision you made to 1 post by another user. That's not a bug, the metric was the same before the design changes and it's what the community wants, in short the number means: *how many posts by other users did you edit*.

Answer (score 22):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Expand Today by Default

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) (or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)? removing useful behavior is usually considered a bug)

The "today" in the reputation summary used to be expanded by default. That was useful. Please restore it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for fixing that!

Answer (score 21):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The Review and Suggestions subtabs under "All actions" show the status of my past reviews, but they're styled as buttons that make it feel like I'm about to vote to approve, reject, etc. The link to the review item itself is valuable and good, but can these be restyled as something less... action-y, please?

[image]

Comment: This has been changed, but frankly into, IMO, something far worse, because it's now far less clear what the review action was when that is one of the useful bits of information for that view.

Comment: This has been fixed, but the only thing I would improve is make the background different color or maybe the text color brighter. In dark mode, it's barely visible.

Answer (score 21):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Here is one of my [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368870/se-is-a-dating-site-revisit-the-last-seen-field/368889#368889) as displayed in the Answers tab:

[image: One of my answers in the display tab]

However, "score" should be used instead of "votes" for the question and answer. For the question, there are 70 up votes and 12 down votes (for a total of 82 votes) giving a score of 58, while for my answer there are 36 up votes and 2 down votes (for a total of 38 votes) giving a score of 34.

Also, as already stated in [Alex Guteniev](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/899239/alex-guteniev)'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372626/562482), my screenshot displays the problem with the answer text showing HTML entity codes, in particular `&quot;` here.

Comment: Also recently mentioned in [New post summary designs on greatest hits now, everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375181).

Answer (score 21):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The badge icon is out of place on the "next badge" progress.

[image: Image of the bug.]

<sup>Image from [my Code Review account](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz?tab=topactivity).</sup>

Comment: The right part of the block is not filled also. Better visible when light mode is on.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ The right part of which block?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Are you talking about the missing part of the progress bar? I don't think the right part is meant to be filled so we can 'visually' see how close we are to getting the badge.

Comment: Shame on me... It's a progress bar. I completely forgot about this.

Answer (score 20):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can we please have a way to see votes on recent questions in the summary tab?

It's much more convenient to get an overview of activity on our recent questions.

[image: screenshot of questions on summary tab of user profile]

Using Windows 10, Firefox 94.0.2 (64-bit), 1920x1080, rev  2021.12.7.40921.

Comment: I came here to say this. I can order my questions by votes, but I don't get to see how many votes each question has.

Comment: I believe this was addressed in recent design refinements.

Comment: @AaronShekey The Answers section indicates whether the **question** has an accepted answer, not whether the **user's answer** is actually accepted.

Answer (score 20):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There's something wrong with the 'Follow post' functionality, even after the fix. Staff can check my followed posts on RPG.SE; on the Summary tab there's just one question:

[image]

while the Following tab has four posts:

[image]

#### Initial version

The 'Follow post' functionality is [FUBAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_slang_terms#FUBAR). The list on the Summary tab is not showing entries which *are* shown on the Following tab, and unfollowing posts from the 'Following' tab doesn't work; the button text updates from 'Unfollow' to 'Follow' but the entry is still there when I reload the page.

[image]

I then tried to unfollow it from the Summary tab. That works, at least when I refresh the page, it's gone, but I can still see it on the 'Following' tab. When I went to the question itself, the link said 'Follow', and now that I clicked that, I'm following it **twice** (note the lack of body for the bottom entry):

[image]

Comment: Is this fixed? I click `Unfollow` and it updates the text, but the entry is still there when I reload. Additionally, it still says "Following" on the post.

Comment: @DanCormier I fear it's still broken, please see my update. I haven't tried (yet) what user17242583 describes.

Comment: I think I faced this issue when preparing for a bug report. Apparently, deleted followed posts are not shown on the "Summary" page (as a non-mod user, not sure for 10k-ers?), but shown on the "Following" page?

Comment: Regarding "following twice", based on [my bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372864), only followed answers are showing the question body, while the question itself doesn't show anything. So you might be following a different post altogether.

Comment: And I think I repro'd the "Unfollow" bug: seems currently it's only working for the questions, not answers. // cc: @user17242583

Comment: Needing multiple clicks to unfollow is also an unreasonable extra step. It used to be a single button only

Answer (score 19):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In profile, rep +2 for Wiki Tag Edit does not show text:

[image: Profile with rep +2 wiki tag edit]

Comment: Ah, thank you for the bug report! Expect a fix soon.

Comment: @DanCormier In the old design there was a different text for tag wiki body and excerpt edit, now it always says "tag wiki". And it would be nice to include the tag name as well.

Comment: It seems to me that it also needs to say to which tag it corresponds ...

Comment: Current Description: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGQqh.png

Comment: Full Description (include tag name): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibZvH.png

Comment: @DanCormier: [Include tag name for tag wiki edits in the reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374497/include-tag-name-for-tag-wiki-edits-in-the-reputation-history)

Answer (score 19):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On the reputation page:

[image]

Downvotes are supposed to be red, not green!

Comment: In fact, any negative reputation change are now shown as green on that page.

Answer (score 18):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Negative reputation changes show as "+-[x]" instead of as "-[x]"

If I incurred a negative reputation change from a post, that used to only show as "-[x]" in my reputation log. However, it's now showing as "+-[x]".

I think the system is pulling in the negative number from the change and putting a plus sign in front of it regardless.

> [image]

Answer (score 18):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the Profile / Reputation when fully expanded "pretty" word is used instead of expected space:

[image: agoprettydec]

Answer (score 18):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## MathJax wraps awkwardly on the activity page

On math.se, certain titles involving MathJax get wrapped strangely on the new activity page. Here's a screenshot from the [comments section of my activity page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21412/kreiser?tab=activity&sort=comments) to demonstrate what I meant:[image]

These MathJax expressions shouldn't take up three or more lines by themselves.

Reproduction details: screenshot produced on Chrome 96.0.4664.45 running on Windows 10.

Comment: Seems to be the same bug as [MathJax text broken along several lines in post titles (in review queues)](/q/369812/289905). No repro on Firefox Nightly 96.0a1.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with Safari on macOS.

Comment: I have also seen the same problem with Microsoft Edge 93.0.961.38 on 64-bit Windows 10.

Comment: FYI, basically the same issue is also reported in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375474/562482) to another post.

Answer (score 18):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When switching to "track a tag badge instead", pressing the gear doesn't let you choose another badge. Reloading the page fixes it.
And those 2 gear icons look misaligned.

Bonus: the tooltip exceeds its bubble.
[image]

---

And this doesn't look good, either.

[image]

Comment: Also:
1. Hovering over another item doesn't move the highlighting to it;
2. Clicking outside of this menu doesn't close it.

Answer (score 18):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Answer text shows HTML escapes such as `&quot;`, `&gt;`, etc.

[image: " example]

Answer (score 18):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### The only useful link in the review history is tiny

Now that [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372612/165261) is fixed, the only part of the review history item that anyone would ever want to click on is a tiny link in the upper left (that doesn't even look like a link.

Compare the sizes of the click targets:

[image: A screenshot of a review item in the review history with the small "Approve" notated with "this is the only thing I ever want to click", the larger title notated with "this links to the post, not the review item", and the large void of space off to the right notated with "the rest of the item is not clickable"]

I can't see why anyone would ever want to go to the post that a review item is for, so the relative size of the click targets here doesn't really make sense.  Ideally, the entire thing (or at least *most* of the space) should link to the review item, since the review item itself also links to the post.

My use case for this page is clicking a large number of these open into new tabs in order to write up flags for reviewers who are reviewing incorrectly ([examples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371786/165261)).  The fact that they are so much bulkier (requiring more scrolling and keeping my place in a long list) **and** the only useful click target is now smaller makes an already thankless and tedious task even more tedious.

Comment: The layout has now been rearranged, but this issue persists.

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I'm not seeing any vote counts in the "questions" and "answers" section, just "votes" without any number in front of it. Here's a screenshot from my [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/50583/acuriousmind?tab=questions) section:

[image]

(OS: Win 10, Browser: Firefox 94.0.2 (64-bit))

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) / [support](/questions/tagged/support) [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I'm not sure exactly what these green bars are meant to represent on the `?tab=topactivity`/`?tab=summary` tabs:

[image: Image of new reputation preview from Activity page on my profile]

This looks like it's meant to preview what the [Graph portion of the Reputation page does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBjlt.png), but without any timestamps/labels, these green bars don't really indicate much of anything. It feels like the preview is too zoomed-in or the `flex--item w100` class divs are cut off in some fashion.

Could you clarify if this is a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug in the code, but it is a design bug in the sense that it's unclear what this is. This is a reputation change graph (which I think could for sure be made more obvious). Thanks for reporting!

Comment: They used to have information when you moused over them, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @DanCormier -2 is green in the screenshot.

Comment: This is the same charting we've done before, but it's a little weird that there's no labeling at all. The style on this has been refined a bit since you've called this out. I'm marking this one as completed but we may want to use a tooltip yet.

Comment: That `-2` should now be red as expected.

Comment: I'm red-green colorblind so I didn't really even notice before until Random Person pointed it out. That said, looks good @AaronShekey ! Thanks-much!

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

There's something wrong with the 'track your next tag badge' functionality. The popup shows but the list is empty for the 'Available' tab:

[image]

and, as @Werner notes, the other tabs show *regular* badges, not tag badges:

[image]

(This could be limited to users which have already access to the full list of privileges.)

Comment: Related... trying to change the "Next tag badge" to track displays "normal badges", not tag badges in the "Available" tab.

Comment: Related: ["Select your next badge" modal displays badges with incorrect width and positioning](/q/367433/289905).

Comment: @DanCormier I can still reproduce the first part here on Meta.SE (FWIW not on Apple.SE). Also, on all sites, the second part is still a problem. It's simply not possible to track another tag badge ... Also reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372688/295232) by user Rick.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue by checking your profile @Glorfindel but if I check mine or Dan's for example, it does display the tags to track. Weird.

Comment: I believe this was an issue from before the recent changes to Activity. On @Glorfindel's Activity page, could this be happening because they've earned all available tag badges?

Comment: (Earlier comment deleted) We're somehow not showing the tag badges here, despite the call looking to be the exact same. Looking into it further.

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

When I go to my **[Reputation / Post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc?tab=reputation&sort=post)** page to show my recent reputation changes by posting, ***no posts are displayed***:

[image]

Instead, an enormous amount of whitespace is displayed, with some numbers and dates.  Before, I would also see posts with recent votes.  Now I must click, and click, and click some more to see what posts got voted up or down.  Before, the page showed the information that I needed and expected.  Now, it shows whitespace, and not much else.  Maybe appropriate on a phone, but I'm not writing answers on a phone.  Given my history of tendonitis and RSI injuries, this added burden of multiple picks is painful both literally and metaphorically.

The same problem exists on the **[Reputation / Time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc?tab=reputation&sort=time)** page, though perhaps that's defensible since it does at least show dates (but not times):

[image]

If the design is supposed to be responsive, why not adapt to the larger screen space that desktop users have, rather than making us click and click and click some more to get information that was previously available at a glance?

Please try to reduce the burden of screen picks so that it's no worse than before.

(Not sure if this is a bug or feature request or what.  In the fields where I've worked, increasing the number of picks required of users without strong justification would be a considered a regression.)

Comment: Related: reports by [KRyan](/a/372627/289905), and [user17242583](/a/372649/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon - right, thanks.  I was just trying to state my difficulty with the new UI in the most objective way possible.  Hence, "No posts shown on the post reputation page, multiple clicks required to see the information that was displayed by default before" rather than "lots of space wasted."

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

The answers section in the summary shows all answers as being accepted even if they're not.

[image]

Comment: This has been mentioned [in the comments of this report](/a/372716/289905).

Comment: @Vanny This appears to have been fixed, at least for me. Can you please confirm whether the [tag:status-planned] on this post should be updated to [tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Summary Overflow™ in tooltip description of "people reached"

I'll...let the image describe itself:

[image: Overflowing text in speech bubble]

To describe, the text for the "people reached" tooltip extends beyond the speech bubble.

Comment: [Same bug occurs on the "Choose between tracking your next privilege and a tag badge" tooltip.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4jED.png)

Comment: @RyanM [This report](/a/372632/289905) links to this one and mentions this.

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Wrong pluralization: "1 answers"

[image]

Comment: Yep. I can see that!

Comment: Same thing for questions.

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Perhaps the inverse of [Choosing a new tag badge to track is not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372633/295232) - I've just earned a *regular* badge on Worldbuilding SE:

[image]

but when I click 'Track the next one' all I see are *tag* badges:

[image]

When I click a badge, it tries to save my choice with a POST call (relevant part below):

```
curl 'https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/activity/next-badge-popup/save' -X POST 'fkey=...&badgeDatabaseName=technology&isTagBadge=true'
```

but the call silently fails and returns the 'Reputation' widget:

[image]

After clicking 'Let us pick', the situation reverted back to normal. This was not just a one-off; this morning I was able to reproduce it on UX.SE.

Comment: I haven't narrowed it down more, but if you click enough times between [both track next badge dialogues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375094) they will get stuck after a while.

Comment: Still an issue, this just happened to me here on MSE, I just earned Civic Duty and it kicked me over into selecting a tag badge when I tried to pick the next one to track. Has nothing to do with clicking between things as it was my first click on a new tab where I opened my profile via middle click.

Comment: This is still [happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH5sv.gif).

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

It looks mostly good except some users ([example](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/26271/davislor)) on mobile have this mess in their profile, (plus the popups expand right, creating a scroll bar):

[image: Mess]

(There are a variety of privileges that trigger this.)

Comment: Yeah, that's rough. Thanks for reporting! Expect a fix in the near future.

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

If there's a huge word in the title of a question, please show at least part of the word to avoid wasting space. This happens in portrait mode in mobile.

[image]

This is how the title is displayed in landscape:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I think it's great to have responsive profile and activity pages! But I wish you would prioritize the pages that currently just don't work at all on a small screen. Please don't see this as a negative comment, I'm very appreciative of the effort you guys put into the platform.

1. When there's an edit suggestion for a question, clicking on the "Edit" link brings up a dialog box to review the edit. This box stretches outside of the screen, there is no way to scroll to see the left portion of this box.
2. When editing the list of duplicates of a closed question, it is again a dialog box that stretches outside of the screen. This time it is impossible to reach any of the buttons on this dialog box.

I need to disable responsiveness to do either of these activities on my phone. With a non-responsive page, I can at least zoom and scroll my way around to accomplish these tasks. But of course it's a frustrating experience.

Comment: We feel your pain! Our goal has been to start 2022 with each view responsive and all mobile views deprecated. We've prioritized that work mostly from least to most impactful so we can refine our approach along views that see less traffic. We're nearing the end of that process and finally getting to views like the Q&A page. In 2022, we plan to refine the design and interaction further so issues like you noted should be fixed in the somewhat near future. We know it's frustrating to deal with these UI issues and thank you for being patient!

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

When I click the gear to track a different badge, the layout changes from 2 columns to one column, moving the "next badge" block under "newest" for a moment.

[image: badges bug]

##### UPDATE

And now is even worse, the medal is quite outside of its border:

[image]

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue, but it didn't happen as you describe. Waiting for someone else to test it out as well. If anyone did, please comment here, as it would help a lot. =)

Comment: @Vanny If that can help, I'm on a 1920x1080 monitor. It happens both on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @vanny also reproed here, and reported, which will now be deleted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372764#372764

Comment: @Vanny it could be that it only happen on specific badges - Enlightened and Sportsmanship are both pretty long single word badge names, causing the elements to not fit on a single line properly and wrap.

Comment: @Andrew it happens with pretty much every badge with an xx/xx counter. With *Research assistant* and *Legendary* the layout stays on 2 columns, but the button moves up a bit when trying to change the badge to track. It doesn't happen if the badge have no counter, like *Altruist* and *Benefactor*.

Comment: The badge layout has been [reported separately](/a/373043/289905).

Comment: I reported as a separate post here: [Badge symbol on activity page "Next Badge" progress out of place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374124)

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

### Changes from votes that don't affect reputation (capped votes, community wiki votes) no longer show in the reputation history

It seems that reputation changes from votes that did not affect your reputation (votes you received after hitting the daily reputation cap as well as all votes from community wiki posts) aren't shown in the Reputation tab anymore.

This was the only way to know when others voted on our own community wiki posts, as these changes didn't show up anywhere else. Now, it's no longer possible to see a history of when people voted on all of our own community wiki posts.

Also, entries of votes that didn't count toward our reputation because it hit the cap don't show in the log anymore either. I still found these useful, because it let us know that we were receiving votes and why or why not some votes counted and not others. Having these entries visible made it a lot easier to distill info and give answers to users asking meta questions with screenshots of their history.

It also made it easier to track persistent cases of serial voting when one had already reached the cap or was close to reaching it: if one receives serial upvotes and has already hit or was close to hitting the cap, only a small amount (or none) of the votes will be shown, making it confusing why the voting was reversed, and harder to report those cases which weren't auto-reversed.

The [/reputation audit page](/reputation) shows capped votes that didn't count toward rep, but doesn't show voting on community wiki posts. This page is unlinked, though, and I don't want to have to repeatedly go there to see if all my rep is legitimately gained.

Comment: I have an upvote for a CW answer showing on my rep page.

Comment: Maybe this is already fixed, but this works for me ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVAGn.png) are some upvotes past the daily cap).

Comment: @RyanM Ah, it seems to have been fixed. I earned some capped votes that weren't showing at the time I posted this, but are now showing.

Comment: It also looks fixed on my end as well, will appreciate more feedback from others!

Comment: It might well be fixed here but I suspect not on  the answers section - e,g, on my Ask Different top voted - the answers section shows 152 but the actual question shows 179

Comment: But then on my top SuperUser answer - which was capped - the answers section shows 145 and the question 68 and what the second answer is doing who knows - it shows as 214 votes but is sorted below the 145 votes

Answer (score 14):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the reputation history, do we really need to duplicate the date in the entries themselves? I feel like some vertical space can be saved here.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

In some tabs (e.g. Revisions and responses) the timestamp is almost isolated far on the right. While this makes sense in some Q&A tabs because it aligns with the tags it could make more sense in other tabs to group it at the top with the other info. This would make the view more compact and allow for better use of vertical space by removing an almost empty line.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

On the "revisions" page each revision starts with "revised". Why is that necessary? Isn't that a little bit obvious, since you know, this is on the "revisions" page?

Please remove that unnecessary heading, which will condense the page.

[image]

---

Previously, when you tried to expand revisions too quickly, you got annoying red popup telling you to wait because of the rate limit. It has been super annoying and I am glad it's gone. Now when you open them too fast, the content just says "Request failed". It's not very informative and it looks like this is the actual content of the edit.

[image]

Comment: Similarly, every item on the "Reviews" page says "reviewed"...I'd hoped it might at least say "Review audit passed" on audits, but it doesn't.  Also, every comment says "comment".

Comment: This was okay back when it didn't take up vertical space, but now that it does...it really shouldn't.

Comment: Also the labels for Accepts, Badges, Suggestions are redundant. The only two tabs where the label is useful are All and Posts, because these actually can contain different types of items.

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Sorting Questions by `Views` no longer actually shows the views for each question.

This is a big regression and hurts the usability of the sort-by-views feature.

[image: sorted by Views]

Comment: Already kind of mentioned by [Dharman](/a/372658/289905).

Comment: @aaron-shekey are you saying this has shipped in the recent fixes by marking `status-completed`? It's not fixed...

Comment: @pkamb That's the idea, yeah. Thought I'd fixed this in the last ship!

Comment: So I just reverted locally to prior to our changes. Sorting by votes, views, activity, and newest only ever showed the question's score. Those numbers never changed, so I don't believe this is a regression. I've changed it to show the question's score to be consistent with the original behavior. ✌️

Comment: @AaronShekey can you post a picture of the old version sorted by views?

Comment: @pkamb The numbers of the top viewed and top voted questions are consistent https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmFCK.png

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Adding this as the goal was to have a responsive design.

The select next tag badge/select next badge modal is not responsive on smaller screens. I can only select the badges from middle column. I suggest at least having a horizontal scroll here if not able to make it selectable on mobile devices.

[image]

Comment: We'll get this modal converted as soon as we can! ✌️

Comment: ["Select your next badge" modal displays badges with incorrect width and positioning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367433/818993) was also fixed by this, ty.

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Attempting to expand reputation history entries for specific posts expands the wrong one, or outright fails

When I try to expand the entries for specific posts on a given day (e.g. to see when the votes took place and how many downvotes there are), it either expands the top one always, or outright doesn't expand.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to [my reputation history page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-anonymous-hedgehog?tab=reputation).
2. Scroll to December 7, 2021 (if that date has passed) and expand that date entry.
3. Expand the second or lower entry in that list. It will get stuck with a loading bubble that always appears right below the first entry:

   [image: Loading bubble]
4. Refresh the page. Expand the December 7 entry again.
5. Expand and collapse the top entry. It works fine.
6. Attempt to expand the second or any below entry. The top one will be expanded even though you clicked on a different one:

   [image: Wrong entry expanded]

Notice that the entry you clicked on will have its arrow show as expanded, and not the first one. Clicking the circled arrow to collapse will collapse the top one.

Tested with all user scripts disabled.

Comment: @DanCormier I can still reproduce this (expanding the wrong one): https://i.imgur.com/g19dguh.mp4

Comment: @Dan I can still reproduce this. Note that this is about the _inner_ expandable sections, i.e. when expanding a specific day, _then_ expanding the details for a post (the arrow below “_n_ events”). Toggling any of those that isn’t the first one is buggy.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was able to reproduce it and have a fix in the works.

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The text of the "Track the next one" button is hardly visible:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

We now have two wheels to track next privilege and badge. The wheels are
vertically misaligned.

[image: screenshot track next]

Besides, the tooltip overflows similar to [people reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372601/899239)

[image: screenshot tooltip overflow]

Comment: @Vanny, The cogs are [precisely aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMAXs.png) when using Firefox Android 95.0.0-beta.6 (2021-11-25).

Comment: My report says that site should not have two identical icons located near each other, similar to yours, but different https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372796#372796

Comment: @vitaliis I agree with your post on only having 1 cog (although I only figured out it had a double functionality when I was nearing my first tag badge). There was in fact a post before this one also mentioning the cog, but in that case it was about one of the dialogues not working. So the issues with the cog are proving to require several posts to address.

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The Answers tab has a wider table than the rest of the tabs:

[image]

That table is also not responsive to horizontal scaling (up to a point).

Comment: That's a weird issue @Werner! I'm unable to reproduce this issue. Here's what I see when I try: http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1LYbd-JkuvcYCx39sJvUmV7QZrVOEMVvl Can you check again and see if it's still happening?

Comment: @DanCormier: Still happening; I'm using an up-to-date Chrome (96.0.4664.93). It doesn't show up in Firefox though.

Comment: I checked in Chrome and can reproduce the issue (I originally checked in Firefox)! This issue is due to lack of formatting on long strings in answer excerpts. We have a fix that should ship tomorrow. Thanks for reporting and working to narrow the issue down!

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There's a missing closing parenthesis in the bounty expiration message in the Bounties detailed view.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

My post is similar to this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372631 (that post talks about Reputation tab https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/846219/random-person?tab=reputation, I am talking about https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/846219/random-person?tab=summary).

In the Reputation section of the Summary page, reputation drop is still shown in green colour.

It should be red.

[image: Screenshot of Reputation section of Summary page]

Comment: I believe this one's fixed.

Comment: @AaronShekey Nope. This is not fixed. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ6MD.png Screenshot was taken couple of minutes ago.

Comment: @AaronShekey Welcome. I can confirm that this is fixed. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhpbD.png

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [localization](/questions/tagged/localization) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Some sentences don't use the translations. There are already translations on Transifex for "Accepted answer" and "Summary", but they aren't used. "View answer" isn't available to translate yet.

> [image: Accepted answer/View answer]

> [image: Summary]

Comment: I was going to post just the same. I can confirm this for es.stackoverflow also.

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the All actions section, only two lines of a comment are visible. On my phone screen, at my default font size, that works out to around 110 characters, with no way of revealing the full comment on the Activity page. This makes it very tedious to search comments. [Eg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372772#comment1244620_372049),

[image: Screenshot of comment on Activity page]

Please consider adding a button to display the full comment contents. Note that you could save a line by moving the comment time/date to the top line...

---

This change has been rolled back. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376552/334566

Comment: ... or just show the comment in full, they are not that long

Comment: @Dharman That would be ideal, but I'm willing to accept a compromise. ;)

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Bookmarks of deleted questions should display with a pink background.

Apparently followed posts [do display correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y17j4.png) according to [zcoop98](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/776523/zcoop98).

[My profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/188189/robert-longson) has a bookmark of a [deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351423/account-has-been-deleted) that's visible if you sort by newest. You'd need to be a moderator or have > 10K rep to see this particular bookmark.

Comment: For me, it's not working. Either in bookmarks or followed posts, deleted posts don't have a pink background, they are displayed the same way as non deleted posts. I'm using Chrome in iOS 15.1 - should I open another bug report or can this be un-status-completed?

Comment: @RobertLongson FYI, this issue has now also been posted in this [question](/q/378496/562482).

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Followed answers are shown as their question instead**

On the "Summary" and "Following" pages, followed answers are showing their question instead, including the post icon, the post body, the accepted status, and the stats.

Example: When following a question and 2 of its answers, this is how it looks on the "Summary" page:

- The icon for the answers is shown as "Q" instead of "A"
- Both answers have their accepted status, while only 1 is truly accepted

[image]

And this is how it looks on the "Following" page:

- The icon for the answers is shown as "Q" instead of "A"
- The question doesn't show the post body, while the answers show *the question's body*
- The stats like the number of the answers, the total <s>score</s> votes(?), and the number of bookmarks are using the question. (Views stats is an exception since there's no explicit view counter for each answer, and thus it's by design to use the question's view implicitly)

[image]

---

**Fixed as of current writing:**

- Followed answers are now showing "A" icon and their post body, score, and acceptance status.
- Followed questions are now showing "Q" icon and their post body, score, views, total number of answers, and whether an answer is accepted.

[image]

Comment: Might be related to ['Follow post' functionality is FUBAR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372645/), but this is focusing on the UI specifically.

Comment: Also related to [All answers are shown as accepted when their question has an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372749/).

Comment: Partially fixed: the icons are now showing "A" for answers and "Q" for questions.

Answer (score 11):

I love that you made this video available, but to properly test how this works I would love to have a live demo version of this. That would also allow the CSS-savvy users in the community to tweak the CSS and suggest fixes or improvements where necessary. Can we please get such a version before this launches?

Comment: In order to ship this before a holiday code freeze, we're planning on shipping the Activity page this week. We can't provide a preview beyond the video/images in this post, but we'll make an update to this post to announce the launch and asking for more feedback. For what it's worth, we've incorporated much of the feedback in the replies to this post and we'll be relying on the community to find the edge cases we haven't fully considered and any opportunities to improve the interface.

Comment: Releasing some massive change before holidays and forcing people to use it throughout them before you'll finally come back with some fixes is not a nice idea, @Dan. You could only deploy it on Meta as well, as you used to before. I really hope you're not talking about the New Year holidays...

Comment: @DanCormier Took me reading all the way down to this comment to get some clarity why on earth these changes shipped in the state they are in. You really should have led your announcement with this line *'In order to ship this before a holiday code freeze, we're planning on shipping the Activity page this week.'*

Answer (score 11):

> No functionality has been lost

Pedantically speaking, that's not quite true.

There used to be a hidden way to get to a user's network profile even if that site's profile was listed as a hidden community on their network profile. While the link at the top would be removed, the heading "Account" on the activity tab's Summary page would still link to their network profile anyway. That link has now been removed.

I think it's still useful to have a link there. It's come in handy in many cases, such as if I want to [find their chat profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231545/377214), or if I'm investigating something to report to a moderator.

When users enable a hidden community, they're notified and explicitly agree that the mechanism will only obscure the most obvious details and not more subtle ones. As it's unlikely that users would go to such a deep level to get a network profile, I think this link should be added back, or an alternate way added to get to the user's network profile. (Also, if the user has hidden all of their communities, the network profile's Accounts tab will show nothing anyway.)

Comment: This is an interesting one for me because we've consistently struggled with users wanting their hidden profiles to actually *be* hidden - so, while this may be a loss for some, it seems like an improvement for people who are expecting that hidden status to actually mean something.

Comment: @Catija I say keep hidden, and the posts asking for this have had lots of support.

Comment: This seems to be added back now!

Comment: @user17242583 No, it's not.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, @Sonic. I was only testing for users that had their accounts public.

Comment: FWIW I've written a [user script](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/add-network-profile-link/add-network-profile-link.user.js) that shows the 'Network profile' button on the top right, even for 'hidden' profiles. (It does not reactivate the link you're talking about.)

Answer (score 11):

Any plans on the empty space next to watched/ignored tags in the profile?

If not, why spend a row per tag?

[image: Tags in profile]

Comment: Because all that space goes away in mobile. Mobile First Design

Comment: Good point, but this is the settings page, not Activity.

Comment: @KevinB: Doesn't mean you have to waste all that space on desktop; you could have tags side-by-side when the screen is wide enough for this, and have them automatically rearrange to fit the available screen width, into a single-file column on the narrowest screens.

Comment: @KevinB mobile first is fine in some situations - where you expect mobile to be the bulk of your traffic - that's not SE's user profile though - and anyways the right way to handle responsive design is never to just pad with whitespace to fill the screen.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion... I wasn't stating this design is what we should be striving for in a mobile first design, more, that it was designed for mobile first, and then the second part of mobile first design was entirely ignored (aka making it responsive toward larger monitor sizes) until after launching it.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Questions on many tabs are shown as having '1 bookmarks':

[image]

(I checked the Questions, Bookmarks and Bounties tabs, but it's probably implemented as a shared component anyway.)

Comment: Where's the number for "votes"?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ has already been fixed (I think) in another report

Comment: @DanCormier Wondering if this is still planned. It's been more than two months and nothing seems to have progressed.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog Yep, it's still planned. In fact, this issue should be resolved when we make the switch from the specialized post summary component used here (and in "Following") to the shared component we use in most other instances of the post summary. We have a branch that needs adjustments to account for the menu in the top right corner, so it's in the works (but may still be a week or two before it ships). These pluralization bugs, while annoying, are relatively low priority but they'll be resolved.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Entries in the list of tags on the Summary page and the Tags page say "1 posts":

[image]

Comment: This is not limited to this location. There's other spots as well (1 votes, 1 answers, ...).

Comment: @Werner true; it turns out "1 answers" [was already reported shortly before this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372639/295232). OTOH, some UI elements *do* properly support plurals.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Please put the date in a consistent place:

[image]

I get that on very small widths it is necessary to put the date on a new line at some point, but when the tags already span two lines, the date doesn't need a third. Can this third example be made consistent with the second row here on the Questions activity page.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a portable, reusable way to guarantee tucking that date up there in every context, especially when there's the potential to have a username and such in that same area. Worth exploring upstream on our [post summary component](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary) though.

Answer (score 10):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

On some sites, e.g. the non-English Stack Overflow sites and English Language & Usage, the graph in the reputation widget is pushed down. This makes them look ... off ... and leads to enlarged 'Badges' and 'Impact' widgets as well.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is how it looks on other sites:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Under the Activity tab, the **Navigation** title to the different activities selection is clickable, but it doesn't link to anything. Additionally, "View all activity pages" is also clickable, suggesting a view of something that isn't available.

[image]

Rather remove "View all activity pages", leaving the title **Navigation** and remove the clickability.

Comment: It’s not a link, it’s a `<label>` which focuses the `<select>` underneath it; it doesn’t seem to expand the drop-down, unfortunately, but please don’t remove it. _“View all activity pages”_ suggests that there are multiple different Activity pages / views, so it does attempt to communicate what “Navigation” is for, but it could be a bit clearer.

Comment: @SebastianSimon: True. There's some miscommunication in the labelling. In general it should be improved to deliver a better message.

Comment: @SebastianSimon is correct, the label selects the `<select>` element but doesn't expand it. That's a browser default, so it's working as intended. Revisiting the labeling seems worthwhile though.

Comment: @DanCormier: Should I write-up a new answer to address the labelling? Or would this suffice... just checking since the [meta-tag:status-bydesign] tag was added, so not sure whether this will be looked at further.

Comment: Related: [this report](/a/372721/289905).

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The recent tab of the badges section used to order newest to oldest badges vertically in columns. Now they are ordered horizontally in rows. It was much easier to understand the progression and follow it visually with the older layout. Can this be reverted to how it was?

[image: screenshot of badges]

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Please bring back the exact time in the reputation tab in the "time" view.

Currently, the time shows when in "post" view, but is hidden in "time" view unless there is a collapsable post. This is what I see now:

[image]

As you can see, when there is a post that can be expanded the time shows, but in all other cases there is no time. It would be much more consistent to show it all the time.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Please compare these screenshots of the reputation page,

Sorted by post:

[image]

Sorted by time:

[image]

Can we please be consistent in the use of a red fill?

Comment: Was about to add this.. Also, there seems to be a difference in card background color in dark mode.

Comment: @SurajRao yes there is a difference in background, but I think that is intentional, and a good thing. In this way the posts that belong to a certain date are visually distinguishable from other dates. A bit like how a blockqoute would work.

Comment: Sure.. I didnt say the grey background is bad.. Its not present for sort by post although the sort by post also has it date wise...

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Make the headers on summary page links to subpages or add a link for "reputation".

There is a small link under "answers" and "questions" and everything else, but there is no link for "reputation" section. The blue link is for something completely different.

[image]

Maybe, it would be a good idea to move the blue link below the list and in its place put a link to the "reputation" page? Or maybe it would be a better idea to make the headers clickable.

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

**Is the "View answer" link really necessary?**

Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64

When I select *Answers** from my Activity page, both the question's title and the option to "view answer" are identical links to my answer.

[image]

**Q**: Is there a need for two things in close proximity that do the same thing?

Also, by removing the "View answer" link the layout would then match the Questions page for consistency (and, in my opinion, be more aesthetically pleasing)...

[image]

---

*Or via the "View all..." option

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Posts background on different listings do not change when the post is deleted.

E.g. this is a followed answer and is looks like this on the list:

> [image]

While the answer itself was deleted:

> [image]

Same with a followed question:

> [image]

Which is actually deleted:

> [image]

Not having this info on the list directly it's quite inconvenient.

Same happens in other listings, as "Bookmarks", etc.

Comment: Maybe this is more a `feature-request` than a `bug`? I don't remember what the behavior was in the old profile.

Comment: I consider it a bug. It used to work correctly, using the "deleted" background for deleted posts.

Comment: This is a bug. First of all it used to be like that. Second, I find it very useful. Once in a while I go over my followed post and like to "clean" the list by unfollowing the deleted ones...

Answer (score 9):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

It would be nice if all of the code blocks could be contained inside the table. It doesn't seem to do this for at least the "Posts" under "All actions". I know the word "under" is incorrect. It should probably be:

> In the submenu of "Posts" in the menu of "All actions"

Example:
[image: Very wide codeblock that extends way past the table]

Note that the width of the table is around the dates "Apr 17" and "Mar 17" at about 1/4 of the total width here. The window is this wide because the post above expanded it to that, and it doesn't seem to come back, once the window has been expanded.

Comment: @DanCormier I'm still getting this under "All activity" in "All Actions" when I drop down some of the "revised" items. Except it takes the entire table with it.

Comment: @DanCormier You have marked this post as status-completed. But it is not at all completed. This issue seems to be in every single tab where it's possible to expand a post. What do you suggest I do to un-status-complete this until it's actually really status-completed? Meaning this issue is no longer present on the entire profile page including every tab?

Comment: I mistakenly tagged this as completed and I've now switched the tag to planned. Expect a proper fix soon.

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

The link 'x prior review suspensions' (visible for moderators after clicking 'Account info') overflows on smaller screens:

[image]

Comment: We're going to ship this bit separately, but it's in the works.

Comment: @AaronShekey thank you, this one is indeed low-priority.

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

After [this FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372611) that asked to restore numbered changes in the blue dots. I can notice **the number is not centered within the dot** so creating an awkward visual impression.

[image: screenshot of number in dot in side menu]

Comment: I've captured this as a [bug upstream](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/802) in our design system. This is related to Windows' Segoe font having a lower baseline than the other system fonts.

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Any reason upvote has green background, but downvote/closure only red text, so upvotes stands out more?

[image: screenshot with upvote/downvote/closure]

Comment: positive reinforcement

Comment: What does "upvote" mean? "This post has at least one up vote"? Then shouldn't it be _upvoted_?  "This post has a positive score"? Then shouldn't we just see the score? Actually, shouldn't we always just see the score? Does it maybe mean "Click this button to upvote"? That's what seems most reasonable, it reads as the imperative of the verb _to upvote_.

Comment: It is votes history, so probably _upvoted_, and no score, since a user can upvote just once

Comment: Since this is a list of *votes* (rather than posts), labelling them as *upvote* or *downvote* sounds perfectly reasonable to me. It shouldn’t be labelled *upvoted*, because it’s not the vote that’s been upvoted; the post has been.

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

When you have offered multiple bounties of different values, the columns don't line up all that well (talking about the summary page). For instance, on [my profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/560258/ekadh-singh-reinstate-monica?tab=summary), the columns saying the score of the post I offered bounties on don't line up:

[image: Screenshot of "Offered bounties" section in which the "+100" bounty slides the next column over relative to the "+50" bounties]

Can this please be changed to make the comments line up more?

Comment: The usual practice in this case is not lining it up. If you group elements of different size on the same line they'll be misaligned between different lines, **or** you'll can align them vertically leaving empty space between the elements. The former option is overall preferable in this case.

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

*Newest* badge is not aligned with *Next badge*.

[image: Screenshot of badges in Summary]

---

This is how it looks now:

[image: Screenshot of badges in Summary]

I think it can be improved further.

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Why are these signs (< >) there in *Responses* tab (for *Answers* and *Revisions*)?

[image: Screenshot of Responses -> Answers]

[image: Screenshot of Responses -> Revisions]

Comment: Try to expand the post, these arrows actually are scrollbar, but weird.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ hmm.. but I am unable to scroll the scrollbar. So what's the point of having it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSyrZ.png

Comment: Seems just invalid content width calculation leads to this behavior.

Comment: The width calculation of all the content is invalid I guess.. @αλεχολυτ

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Also, why should scroll bars be shown before expanding the post?

Answer (score 9):

The design isn't great unless you're on mobile (I logged in for the first time on my phone and hit over to the desktop site just to check it out) - though it is much better now than it was this morning, there's still a few issues:

First the amount of content - there used to be more. Every section now seems limited to 5 items (or less in sections with other content like the reputation preview). Taking up more space for less content still isn't great, and nowhere is this more noticeable in the tags section, where before I had more than double the tags showing for my top tags, with 2 or 3 per line, rather than 5 even bigger lines of 65% to 79.3% wasted white space.

Second the summary responsive sections. At my full screen size (1900 x 1820) the summary section is three panels side by side which all look fine. I dragged the browser to the edge of the screen to get windows to tile it at half width (two side by side windows) and got this. It looks fine on other sites where I have 2 or all three badge classes, but if you only have bronze badges, the full width badge bar with  the centered number looks overly stretched.

[image: badges]

<s>Third, the look of the reputation preview itself. I can't go back and verify it of course, but I believe the old design had space between the bars for the days - the new design is harder on the eyes, with wider bars and no separation, and if a user has pretty consistent changes, makes it hard to tell how many days the graph represents.</s>(This has been changed, thank you)

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Wrap Answers and Questions on Summary if two columns view is engaged, like reputation:

[image: Answers and Questions on Summary]

Comment: I would be inclined to mark this as a bug, since it's inconsistent behavior between layouts on the same page

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Results for suggested edits are in the wrong tense:

[image: suggested edits listed as "Approve"]

I didn't *approve* these suggested edits, I suggested them. They were then later *approved*. Similarly, suggested edits which used to be listed as "Rejected" now say "Reject"

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Answer timestamp overflowing answer component (on the SO activity page, *Newest* and *Activity* tabs, and most likely *Votes* too, though this answer isn't highly upvoted).

[image]

In this second example, the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795444/)'s title is "Reading " followed by a long path that is technically one word.

[image]

Reproduced in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I see this happen when time is displayed as elapsed time ("... ago"). Dates are displayed correctly.

Comment: related overflow (but where the title also overflows): https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBrum.png

Answer (score 9):

<s>[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)</s> [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

<s>Bring back the faint yellow coloring of the new reputation events.</s>

Fix the faint yellow coloring of the new reputation events when sorting by Post

> Why are events sometimes highlighted in yellow?
>
> This represents new events that you haven't seen yet regarding your reputation. They are only highlighted for that single view of the page. If you leave and return to your reputation history, they will no longer be highlighted. The total amount of the highlighted events should add up to the number in the bubble of the reputation tab itself (excluding any removed and reversal events). This bubble is meant to indicate the total amount your reputation has changed since you last checked the reputation tab. It will not appear until you've visited the tab at least once.
>
> — [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139615/392799)

Update: I just (Dec 21) noticed that the yellow highlighting only works when sorting by Time, and not also by Post as it used to:

> [image]

So I've changed it to a bug report.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Followed posts start with an empty line if the post title is long. (In the activity summary.)

[image: screenshot of followed posts in summary]

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

There's some inconsistency in the punctuation between sections without items in the activity summary. Some have a full stop (e.g. Articles, Reputation, Bookmarks)  while other don't have a full stop (e.g. Votes cast, Bounties, Answers, Questions).

[image: screenshot of section in activity summary]

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

There are text overlapping on Reviews tab on [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84?tab=activity&sort=reviews):

> [image]

Comment: This is what happens when localized content tries to fit in a 96px `width` box [wink wink]

Comment: @OlegValter when респонсивнэс meets localization.

Comment: This also happens on non-localized sites for the longer descriptions like *"edit and leave closed"*.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ more like стрэтчинес - not sure I can call the redesign truly responsive in the technical sense of the word.

Comment: Confirmation of issue on non-localized sites: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf2x0.png

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Sorry, SO, but to me, this is one of the worst releases in a long time. Have you taken feedback from users before deploying it? I'm sure you did, however, from the sheer amount of <strike>negative</strike> constructive feedback, it seems you haven't properly gone through the UI/UX processes (e.g. focus groups).

There are a lot of things in the new UI that makes it more difficult for me to grasp the information on the profile page. As others have said, the information density change is a regression here:

- there's less information shown in the same amount of space
- we are shown information that we don't necessarily care about, adding to more space wasting

There is room for improvement, here's one suggestion from me regarding the reputation tab.

Currently, it looks like this:
[image]

This wastes three lines, which could fit very well into one:
[image]

Comment: Can’t remove “upvote”; this is what tells you what caused the positive reputation change. I think I’d prefer two lines in that box: first one says “+10 upvote · 3 hours ago”, second one includes the title. Although, the timestamp doesn’t always appear…

Comment: @SebastianSimon the "upvote" part can be inferred from the green color of the score box. It can be added maybe right before the score change, so we keep everything on one line.

Comment: Approved suggested edits, accepts (both passive and active), bounties, and the association bonus also add to your reputation; these are very different events. Not every positive reputation gain is from an upvote.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, good point, and the actual score doesn't help discriminating about the reason in all cases, for example 10 points can come either from an upvote, or voting correction.

Comment: This is one of the changes that I suggest [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372695/165261), but I like the mockup.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Answer text hard-wraps on "answer" tab:

[image: BUG]

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There is no need to include the number of bounties in parentheses:

[image]

The number is duplicated in reference below it ("View all # bounties"), like all the other boxes. And when there's no bounty (0), this is described in the box.

Please remove it.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

#### Insufficient contrast between text and background on chip for questions with accepted answers

[image: "9 answers" in white on pale green]

The contrast ratio between the white and pale green is 2.52:1, less than the [WCAG standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Understanding_WCAG/Perceivable/Color_contrast) of 4.5:1 for body text, or even less than the standard for large-scale text (which this isn't) of 3:1.

Qualitatively, it's also just kind of difficult to read.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please switch back to black colour in Ask Ubuntu.

[image: Screenshot of Questions tab in Activity in Ask Ubuntu]

The orange colour looks yucky!

Comment: Orange Is the New Black :)

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Tooltips for [bookmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bookmarks) remove/unremove item look reversed. E.g. click on bookmarked post shows "Remove bookmark" menu item and "Bookmark this question" tooltip:

> [image: Remove bookmark]

Similar situation after the click was made.

> [image: Bookmark]

Futhermore, it seems that tooltip is even more correct than menu item. I.e. the bookmark is deleted when I press "Bookmark" (sic!) item. Click on "Remove bookmark" returns the question to bookmarks list. You can test it by reloading the page.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Tab bar (on "All actions" subpage) bounces to different position on some condition (seems depend on title width). The following GIF is from my ruSO profile page:

> [image: bounce]

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When you downvote a post and then vote to close, the vote tab gets broken. Trying to expand the downvote before expanding the closure vote breaks UI.

[image]

The post above has a weird loading icon that is flickering. The content does not load.

If I press the closure button first and then the downvote, it loads the content but under the closure instead.

Comment: Despite the similar appearance to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372620/165261), this is a different bug, and still broken even after that was fixed.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

For the current logged in user and for moderators the total number of network accounts should count hidden accounts too.

The display is correct for viewing other people's accounts if you're not a moderator as it correctly does not count their hidden accounts.

My own total account count for example should be 21 when I look at it, but 10 when any other non-moderator looks at it. After all if I've 11 hidden accounts I can hardly have 10 accounts in total. And of course if I click on the link, I will be shown all 21 of my accounts.

[image: Hidden and total accounts]

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In some cases I think the empty sections in the summary page stick out like a sore thumb. For example, in the following screenshot the bounties tab actually has information but takes up 2.5X less space than the empty Accounts section.

[image]

The issue becomes more noticeable for profiles that mix used sections with empty sections. In this example I have to scroll through 1 full screen of nothing...

[image]

Until finally getting to the voting summary at the bottom...

[image]

Can the empty sections be made shorter vertically if unused?

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When you expand and contract a post highlighted in the Votes tab, the box doesn't close to the same vertical position:

[image]

Comment: @DanCormier: ...I still see this as an issue under Chrome. With the [tag:status-completed] tag, will this be rolled out later?

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals)

In the [Activity -> Summary -> Bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=summary#user-panel-bounties) section, for "1 bounty" the text is displayed as "1 bounties".
It was properly handled in the [Activity -> Bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties) menu. Can this be fixed?

**Screenshot for reference:**
[image: 1 bounties]

Comment: something deprecated about something deprecated with something deprecated. Seems like there are quite a few pluralization issues this time around

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I see two same icons in my profile Summary near Next tag badge

Chrome 96, Linux 20.04

[image]

Comment: already reported: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372632/361484

Comment: @Luuklag The other report [you commented on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372796#comment1244996_372796) complains that the two icons are misaligned; that's no-repro for me. This report is that there are two identical icons next to each other that perform different functions, the implication being that each should have a distinct and function-differentiationing appearance so one doesn't have to tap each one (no rollover on Mobile) to distinguish between the two.

Comment: The bug is that the left cog after the text "next tag badge" looks like it duplicates the function of the cog next to the text on the right after the words "next badge". [The leftmost cog should be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxD2k.png).

Comment: Rob is right. The reported issue is different.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

All the green boxes below take you to the relevant activity tab, except for **Reputation**, which heads you over to the reputation league. For consistency, I'd suggest changing this read "View reputation changes" (or similar) and to also head over to the reputation tab.

[image]

One can keep the league reference under the **Summary** tab's reputation, as its an appropriately different location.

Comment: I don't think clicking "top 3% overall" should lead to two different locations. Renaming it on the Reputation-box in the page would make for less confusion, if it leads to somewhere else than the league.

Comment: @Unconsidered: I implicitly meant that the text "top 3% overall" should also be changed to something similar to what is listed with the other boxes, like "View [all] reputation changes". I put [all] here since you'll only be able to see all reputation changes on your own profile. So maybe just "View reputation changes" or "View reputation"... I'll update the post to be more explicit about the text.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate)

The reputation graph used to have a highlight on hover around the bars. That highlight isn't visible and it was useful to count days without scoring on the graph; besides being visually helpful to distinguish which bar on the graph you are on.

It's appears to be shown working [on this recent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372692).

Here's an Image for comparison taken from a much [older post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202315).

[image]

Comment: @Vanny I suppose the current criteria for marking as duplicate is posts addressing different bugs in the same element. That is somewhat unusual since it's not certain if the devs want to retain different functionalities that went missing on the same element. Hence most posts followed the usual method of addressing bugs separately.

Comment: Possible REGRESSION! I think the highlight was working briefly but it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the Badges page the last row always has a single badge.

[image: screenshot of badges page]

Comment: [Not always](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=badges&sort=class&page=3).

Comment: Well, other than the last page…

Comment: 52 badges per page  seems a very odd choice if the idea is to have 3 column display (3*17+1), it makes sense for a 4 column display though (4*13), perhaps this is a legacy of an older 4 column design?

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [localization](/questions/tagged/localization)

There is an invalid pluralization for views with `k` suffix in [questions section of profile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84?tab=questions):

> [image: k views]

Resulting string (with `k` suffix) **should not** rely on precise views count. Otherwise same values like `2k` in the picture above would have different word after the values, actually based on values 2173 and 2105 respectively (this is wrong).

In contrast the correct pluralization wording is used on [site's questions page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Frequent):

> [image: Question list]

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Bookmarks page doesn't link to most recent activity when sorted by Activity

When the Bookmarks view is sorted by Activity, the links on the page are supposed to link directly to the post which had the most recent activity. Now, they only link to the question when sorted by "Activity".

Here's a screenshot showing the first bookmark on my list, and the URL that it is going to (you can see it's the question that it's pointing to, not a specific answer):
[image: Bookmarks page with my mouse hovering over the first bookmark]

And when I go to the question and hover on the date hyperlink under the title (the "Active today" text), it shows me the real location of the recent activity:

[image: The question page's recent activity link showing it isn't the Q that was updated, but an answer somewhere]

Clicking it of course still takes me to where I should have gone in the first place:

[image: The answer with the most recent activity... where I wanted to arrive when I clicked the link from my Bookmarks page]

You can see that's the right place because the dates in the tooltips match in screenshots #2 and #3.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please consider changing colours of Approved and Rejected to green and red respectively.

[image]

Comment: I think the FR about Red/Green for Approved/Rejected suggested edits is really cool (that can also apply to the corresponding reviewer, not just the editor). I was thinking about that but went with posting about the broader possibility of adding further color codes for other actions.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Currently there's one tooltip missing for the posts edited field. There is also an inconsistency in styling between the tooltips.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The Reputation box in the Summary view doesn't list reputation increases for accepting answers as correct:

Reputation box in Summary view:
NB: green bar showing rep increase, but no activities listed
[image]

Reputation view for same user:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In All Actions -using responsive design- most pages now have the timestamps aligned by the end of the title. This does not happen using the page in full screen.

[image: screenshot of all actions]

Answer (score 7):

The "Questions" section of the Activity tab has a misaligned timestamp.

MacOS Catalina, Chrome 96.0, screen 15.4-inch (2880 x 1800).

[image]

Comment: [Already reported](/a/372812/289905).

Comment: No, That one is about Answers section.

Comment: The design is identical.

Comment: I see that it is fixed now.

Answer (score 7):

**Followed posts no longer indicate post status**

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The Followed list previously  highlighted some posts with red background when they were either closed or deleted (I don't remember if closed were included but definitely deleted). This highlighting no longer exists.

The `"[closed]"` that appears in main page list titles does not appear in the new followed UI either.

This makes trying to clean up and unfollow useless posts a tiresome task now not to mention that unfollow used to work with a single click and now requires two.

Please add some decent front end filtering tools to all these lists. Overall the level of user interactivity in the UI is not up to modern day standards.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When selecting a badge to track, tag badges for tags with long names overflow their container. Here are two examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the bug report! We've shipped a fix.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

A vertical separator between daily bars in the reputation graph is missed.

[image: screensnhot of reputation graph]

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The misaligned text bug [reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372074/misalignment-of-summary-data-in-my-activity-questions-sub-menu) seems to have been fixed, but now replaced by random paragraph-returns making one line in to two (but only on my Law Activity page, not my MetaSE):

[image]

Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, and Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it. Hopefully, we can gather more feedback.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [area51](/questions/tagged/area51) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

On Area 51 Discussions, the Reputation widget is trying to load a reputation graph, but it doesn't show (presumably because Area 51 itself is on a very old version of the Stack Exchange engine):

[image]

A similar bug is affecting the Stats block:

[image]

Comment: The “Stats” on the Profile also try to load something. I get a 500 Internal Server Error for `GET https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/rank?userId=` _userId_ `&_=` _timestamp_.

Comment: I am wondering if this one deserves a dedicated post? Because it is Area51...

Comment: It wasn't broken before, AFAIK ...

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

There used to be a color difference when I had (recently) opened a post (in the list of Questions / Answers).  Please get this difference back!

Comment: I am not sure if I understood this... Could you add a lit more context so we know exactly what is the issue and if this is impacting usability?

Comment: I think this is referring to links changing color when they've been visited. Currently, the Stacks post summary doesn't have a `:visited` style. I think it's worth considering.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for explaining @DanCormier

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) using an Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, and Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64

Clicking the "next tag badge" cog icon incorrectly brings up the "next badge" pop-up instead.

I noticed this because I was tracking another tag badge which has been replaced by what I guess is the system's automatic recommendation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also repro-ed on [CGCC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and [CGCC Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/) on Chrome 95, on Windows 10

Comment: Is this the same as [Choosing a new tag badge to track is not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372633/295232)?

Comment: @Glorfindel It's definitely similar and related as they both incorrectly link to "next badge" instead of "next tag badge", but I don't think it's a 100% duplicate as the "available" tab in my pop-up is populated unlike the one in your link which is empty.

Comment: I see the same on "all" sites. However... on other sites, apart from SO, having switched to tracking "my next privilege" and switching back to "a tag badge instead", clicking the "Next tag badge" cog now doesn't do anything; no popup at all!? However, another weird thing... I see the option for "Next tag badge" when viewing someone else's profile! Clicking the cog (on someone else's profile) displays my own "next (normal) badge" popup!? And selecting one changes the next (normal) badge I'm tracking on my profile.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I suggest some tweaks to the CSS of the post summary class:
On the left I changed the border from 16 to 10 px, and the font-size from 1.46...rem to 1.16....rem (only changed the 4 for a 1). This makes so much more room available on the page.

[image]

Another great option would be to prevent the post score (why is it called votes btw?) from going onto a new line at lower screen widths. There really isn't any use for that too happen, it will only create a lot of whitespace. This can easily be done by switching `flex-direction` of the `post-summary` from column to row.

Doing that I'm able to fit both 5 answers and 5 questions on the same place that only had 5 answer and half a question in the original:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) using an Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64

The columns in my reputation's bar graph highlight (or is it lowlight as they go a much darker shade?) when selected as though they are performing a function but none is performed.

Is there a missing link / pop-up?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Implement simple GUI layout change option so we can revert back to the horizontal layout version prior 8 december roll-out on SO.

See my other comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372703/stack-overflow-revert-back-to-gui-layout-prior-launch-of-december-8th-version)

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please remove "**Navigation** View all activity pages".

[image: Screenshot of Activity page]

I feel that the text is superfluous. The drop-down menu makes it obvious to the user that it is related to navigation.

Comment: It's a bit weird that the drop down also is repeated in the section heading. I think the overall design of the navigation among the sections could be improved, although I think it makes sense to try to get version 1.0 of the responsive page done with as little structural change as possible.

Comment: Same for [settings page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371564/339911).

Comment: Related: [this report](/a/372659/289905) and the comments.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Just compare English and non-English layouts:

> [image: MSE]

> [image: ruSO]

The latter looks ugly even on my ultrawide monitor.

Comment: The right hand side is probably caused by breaking the line (responsive-design) because the "view all 139 answers" in Russian doesn't allow enough space to keep the tabs on the same line.

Comment: @bad_coder yep, whatever, that ugly. BTW just noticed that on MSE left block is Questions, and on ruSO Answers is on the left side. It seems that block with more items displayed first.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Which to place first, questions or answers, is based on the activity of the user whose profile is being displayed. It has nothing to do with which site, just what the user has done on the site (i.e. if the system thinks that the user's activity on that site is more weighted towards answers or questions.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

On Stack Overflow the bottom row of the Tags section currently has more height than the other rows.

[image: screenshot of tags reputation sections]

Comment: This happens on every site, not just SO.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can the activity tab on the profile page please be made to remember the last sub?

Like this:

> [image: Profile --> Activity --> Comments]

I usually visit "All actions" or "Votes" to go back to posts I've been interacting with. Now that takes two clicks every time, because it defaults to "Summary".

While I'm at it: if I'm at the "Comments" sub-sub-tab, it doesn't need to tell me that each comment is a comment. Could do with some more content there.

Comment: Indeed saying that each comment is a comment is not needed - same for most other sub-sub-tabs: each accept begin accepted, each badge being awarded, each revision being revised, each review being reviewed, each suggestion being suggested.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I think it's worth mentioning that, should devs and readers not have noticed, the "Research Assistant" badge can be line wrapped due to having a whitespace in the middle. I don't know if it's necessary given the available space. I also haven't seen this happen for any other badges like "Strunk & White" for example.

[image: screenshot of badges in impact section]

Comment: This doesn't happen on [meta.se], but on other sites (specifically [tex.se], where I noticed it); I've noticed the use of a different badge size, which could influence the remaining space.... perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

The Answers and Questions boxes are almost useless now, because they cut off almost all questions short. Here are mine from my biggest profile. Just 1 out of 10 are readable in full. And the others? It's not just that they're cut off at the end, but they're cut off in the middle, before you can tell what they're about. The important part of each question is not visible!

- Can you be a Christian if you don't believe in ... what?
- What is the difference between the Trinity ... and what?
- How do Christians who emphasise the ... what?
- How do Christians who believe in ... what?
- How does the essence-energies distinction ... what?
- When was the "Evangelist" title first ... what?
- Are there published testimonies from ... who?
- What are the major problems that ... what?
- Which Biblical theology frameworks are ... what?

[image: Screenshot of the Answers box]
[image: Screenshot of the Questions box]

Comment: After all the bugs are ironed out, this is what the conclusion will boil down to: Is it better to have a row of tabs, or a side column with those tabs (- links being the same)? The effects on seeing text truncated in the summaries (given the average title length) is an annoyance that can only be mitigated by going back to a row of tabs, **or** expanding those already short rows to accommodate and wrap the title (which would impact the section on the side visually, since e.g. Answers could have all long titles and Questions all short (or none) - creating a 2x row imbalance.) Ahh, the conundrum.

Comment: @Bad_coder the full titles are shown in the reputation box. I'm sure they can work it out for these boxes too.

Comment: Thing is, in the reputation section rows aren't aligned with the neighboring Tags section so it's easier wrapping them. (They also don't have an ending timestamp which further cramps the character count - I haven't found an maximum character count title post yet to see how it looks.) But the front-end team have thus far always found a solution for everything :)

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the tabs of the All actions page the labels have varying alignments with the subsequent text that give an overall sense of inconsistency and a more or less varying impression of being misaligned depending on the tab.

[image: screenshot of labels in all actions tabs]

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The dot on badges [aka *"the bling"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364832) in the badges section of the summary page appears cut on the left side and misaligned vertically (happens using responsive design and using zoom) in Firefox.

[image: screenshot of badges section in summary]

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

On desktop the top of [my profile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/?tab=summary) looks like:

> [image: Next badge on wide screen]

As you can see there is a lot of wasted space in badges area. Despite this the new and the next badges are placed on the single row producing word wrapping for the name of next badge.

At the same time on narrow screen same blocks look much better:

> [image: Next badge on narrow screen]

My suggestion here is to place "new badge" and "next badge" items on the different rows on wide screen, e.g.:

> [image: Suggested design]

Or take other actions to prevent word wrapping on wide screens that makes narrow design much better than in desktop mode.

Update:

It seems that on some cases there are [two rows already](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/474982/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0?tab=summary), but has another issue that the text may overlap the next badge item border:

> [image: Two rows for some cases]

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The amount of whitespace on the *"All actions"* page is extreme.

[image: all actions page]

Why is the timestamp on its own line? Why is there a massive left gutter?

Moving the timestamp into the flexbox row and reducing the left column width from 96px to 70px IMO makes this much easier to read and maximises information density

[image: revised all actions row layout]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372648).

Comment: @bad_coder you're right; I missed yours because I was searching for "all actions". Looks like some of the pages have been revised since your screenshots with the _type_ ("comment", "revision", etc) now on the same row as the title albeit with a ridiculous amount of left padding

Comment: I think the left padding is because [the names of some review items can be very long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372732). So to keep the items in all the tabs of the "all actions" page with the same alignment the items with shorter names end up having that distance to the left edge. I don't know what the solution for this could be....

Comment: I'd argue that this would be a good use for an actual `<table>` :D

Comment: Please no tables, flex is the way to go :)

Comment: Perhaps a grid then. That way the first column could automatically size to the largest cell. The way it's implemented with flex right now means you have to set an arbitrary width to try and fit strings

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please let me see the status of my flags even if I don't have any "helpful actions".

I joined a new site to raise a flag. With no prior history (especially no helpful flags) this is how my activity page looks:
[image: screenshot of activity page with "measure your impact" placeholder where my flag and edit stats should e]

There's a placeholder where my stats should be, providing a link to my flag summary. If my flag gets declined I'll probably be stuck with this state too. As a power user I know where to find the flags without a link, but this is something that users might miss. I don't know how the UI could accommodate this, which is why I think this is a feature request. UX-wise it's more like a bug.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Voting corrections/reversals for votes on questions *only*, when you are the one who cast the votes, don't clearly indicate what happened there. Per a moderator on the site, the case depicted below was one where I cast votes on questions (so, no change in reputation on my part) that were then reversed by the script. Usually, voting reversal includes some votes on answers, or is seen by the person who was voted _upon, so there is some indication of a reputation change.

Given that this is unclear/confusing, could the entry/line item here for such reversals either:

1. Not be shown at all when there is no reputation change (probably the best option since this is the *Reputation* view?

   or
2. Indicate that the reversal was on questions only, thus there was no rep change to record here (could be preferable if you want there to be a public record for all reversals regardless of rep change for the user)?

[image: voting corrected message on the reputation page, but no indication of the amount or direction]

Comment: In this case, based on public information, this is three votes which you made to questions by a single user which were reversed by the automatic reversal script when it was run at 03:00UTC on 2022-01-26 (which usually means the votes were in the 24 hours prior to that time). Given that they were votes you made on questions, the reversal of them has no impact on your reputation, so no reputation change is indicated. Overall, the displayed information is accurate. So, not a bug. OTOH, it's not clear to me that the system *should* show that to the voter when it doesn't impact their reputation.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks, I started updating the answer based on your info in chat but got distracted before I could finish.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Aesthetically, the Answers tabs should have their time stamps line up between the questions and answers. Currently they don't:

[image]

Comment: This makes sense: it makes it clear which timestamp goes to which.  The real issue here is the [poor information architecture of the cells](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372684/165261).

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Currently the daily bars in the reputation graph touch the top. The graph used to have a margin on top which I think was visually more appealing. Can a margin be added so the bars don't touch the top?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate)

Regarding [this previous post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372676) about inconsistent punctuation it also happens in other detailed sections of the activity page other than in the summary. For example in the Undelete tab in the votes page:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64

In my Reputation sub-menu the text in my graph's pop-up, that shows the date and rep, is bottom aligned making it look odd.

[image]

NB, this is not a duplicate of [Columns in Reputation graph are highlighted upon clicking but no function is performed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372692/) which relates to the graph in the top-line Activity page.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate)

The tag-badge settings cog has this pop-up on hovering:

[image]

Quite reasonably it seems to lead to the tag-badge dialogue.

On left clicking the cog, this pops up:

[image]

Which leads to all badges except the tag-ones.

Expected behaviour would be to lead to the tag-badges pop-up dialogue or display of progress.

Windows 10, Brave, latest.

Comment: The same issue appears to have already been mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372688/149167) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372633/149167). (Although this now appears to be fixed for me.)

Comment: Ah, fair enough, they weren't listed in the community post though (as far as I could see). As long as they get to know anyhow. @MrWhite

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The badges icons are not perfectly aligned if one of the groups is empty. I don't dislike the current layout but it's noticeable and can be distracting. Perhaps it would be better to have them aligned?

[image]

Comment: This triggers me more than it should. It's such an obviously basic test that just as obviously wasn't done.

Answer (score 5):

Clicking the badge icon next to a tag in the Tags page opens the page for that tag-badge, not *the page for that tag-badge **for that user***.

1. Visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17242583/user17242583?tab=tags)
2. Click the small brown icon next to [python](/questions/tagged/python)
3. It leads to https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/267/python, but I'm pretty sure before this change it lead to https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/267/python?userid=17242583

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64

I've had a look at a number of different users on various sites and think this only affects my profile - not that I'm paranoid or anything!

My "Questions" box on <strike>both</strike> my [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/35069/rick)  <strike>and [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/906208/rick)</strike> Activity page<strike>s</strike> is misaligned.  It looks like it's got an extra line at the bottom which has pushed it up a few notches.

[image]
**EDIT** on further examination following [@Joundill's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372870#comment1245363_372777), it seems the misalignment is due the lack of:

> View all *n* questions

Comment: I've got the same thing. It's because the text "View all X answers" is there for your answers, but you don't have enough Questions for it to appear for your questions.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please add the hyperlink (https://stackexchange.com/users/19021247/random-person?tab=accounts) for *Accounts* in *Summary* tab.

[image]

[Mobile view has the hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXMhA.png).

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this earlier FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372775) which is the general request of having links on section headers.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

### The reputation graph's selection feature is broken in Safari.

The graph says: *Select an area by dragging across the lower chart.* However, when I do that in Safari 16.1 on a Mac running macOS X 11.6, nothing happens. There's no indication of selection happening when I drag across that lower chart, and nothing changes in the view. Things work as expected if I switch to Chrome, but I'm not about to change my browser to accommodate an SO bug.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

The rows between the Tags and Reputation sections are misaligned.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the All actions page all the tabs have the labels misaligned vertically with the icon and the title.

[image: screenshot of Closure in All actions]

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The spacing between rows in Votes cast seems too much and out of place with the rest of the layout (no other section uses so much distance between rows).

Scrolling around the summary I get the impression it would integrate better visually if the two rows were closer together.

[image: screenshot of comparison between sections]

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The addition of a dangling, parenthesized number of "unhelpful" flags in the IMPACT box seems unnecessary (the number `(15)` below):

[image]

If some flags were "unhelpful," should one perhaps include "unhelpful edits" as well (for example, a count of posts that were rolled back)? No... More motivation for this being somewhat meaningless is the fact that the number only constitutes a portion of what a regular person might consider "unhelpful." The above 15 "unhelpful" flags are only those *declined*, not including those *disputed*, which seem like it may also be considered "unhelpful."

[image]

In short, I don't consider it adding much, if any, value.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't see the value in removing that information.

Comment: I don't presently the number in parenthesis under the flags. (Maybe because I haven't raised unhelpful flags in a while?)

Answer (score 5):

### Answers showing no text

[image: BGSE]

It shows the score and the date stamp of the answer, but it should still be showing the title of the question, some way to identify which answer is which. This also breaks linking to the answer, since the empty `<div class="flex--item fl-grow1 pr12"></div>` is what normally contained the a tag links.

[image: SO]

Confirmed an issue across multiple sites (BGSE and SO) and with different sorting (newest shown on BGSE, votes on SO). Using Chrome Version 96.0.4664.93 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Already reported here and a fix is in progress: [No question titles for user's answers in the Activity tab](/q/374104/289905) and [The “Answers” card on the Activity page does not show any titles](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/414799/4642212). Turns out this is unrelated to the recent Activity page changes.

Comment: @SebastianSimon -  Commenting so as not to clog up the thread with an obviously linked answer but just in case you haven't seen it, the title is also missing from the "View all answers" visible [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page#372889)

Comment: @SebastianSimon Ahh - I had checked on the summary answer here but didn't look for someone posting the issue separately.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

### Missing space between bounty amount and opening parenthesis in the 'Bounties' tab in my profile's 'Activity' tab

In the 'Bounties' tab in my profile's 'Activity' tab on one of the SE sites, the bounty information displayed above the post title looks like this:

[image]

The part within the blue box reads:

> +50(ends in 6 days)

That is, there is a space missing between the bounty amount, '+50', and the information about the duration of the bounty, '(ends in 6 days)'. It looks like this under both, the 'Active' tab as well as the 'Offered' tab.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I'm not sure if this is a bug but the columns in Votes cast stop being vertically aligned if you go below a threshold of resolution.

Up until one resolution (also happens using zoom)

[image: screenshot votes cast 150]

On a lower resolution (also happens using zoom)

[image: screenshot votes cast 170]

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Deleted posts are no longer highlighted in the "Following" tab

This happens on the dark theme, didn't check if it reproduces on the other one too.

This was really helpful for cleaning up the following posts list, as the delete event doesn't bump up the post at the top of the list, even if sorting by activity.

Previously, deleted posts had a redish background, maybe that can be restored, or another indicator be added.

Comment: A similar issue is that deleted posts are also no longer highlighted with the "reddish" (actually, for me, it's seems more like light pink) background in the "Bookmarks" tab as well.

Comment: @JohnOmielan yeah, it might've been some pink nuance, don't exactly remember :)

Comment: The highlighting of deleted followed (and bookmarked) posts was [status-completed] ([Distinguish between deleted and non-deleted posts in bookmarks and followed posts](/q/378496/1099857)).

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Not sure if this question is still followed by SO staff/developers, but please bring back the highlighting of the deleted posts in the "Following" tab.

Previously it was easy to unfollow the deleted posts, since they were highlighted with a pink-ish background, and we had quick access to the "Unfollow" functionality. The entry looked something like this:
[image]

Please notice the pinkish background, and also how easy/intuitive I was able to un-follow the post. Now I have to click on the 3-dot menu to get a single option that reads "Unfollow", and no indication the post was deleted or not, which puts a great burden on my "following behaviour".

Can we have these two back?

- highlighting of deleted posts
- "Unfollow" link instead of one-item-menu

The menu might save space on smaller screens, but we can have both, depending on the screen size, with media queries.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Change "up votes" to "upvotes" and "down votes" to "downvotes" in Votes cast section of Summary tab.

[image: Screenshot of Votes cast in Summary]

Comment: This should have some context. In the internet age the compound word "downvote" has become a proper noun and is lexicalized. Thus it can be written as you propose but it will cause strangeness to a number of readers and personally I have mixed feelings if I prefer it one way or the other. (Does the SE style guide mention this?)

Comment: @bad_coder There’s [Can we downvote "down-vote" and "up-vote" in the Help Center?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382889/4642212), which suggests that “upvote” and “downvote” are the canonical spelling.

Comment: @SebastianSimon that post is about removing hyphens from tags. It doesn't make a canonical conclusion. (But excellent link, I had read that post.)

Comment: The “Justification” section is about how the spellings “upvote” and “downvote” should be preferred over “up-vote”, “down-vote”, “up vote”, or “down vote”.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please show more number of badges when the mobile is in portrait orientation.

[image]

As we can see in the screenshot, the whitespace takes a lot of area and it can be used to show more badges when mobile is in portrait orientation.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The reputation graph in the summary section disappears using a smaller display of responsive design (also if using zoom).

Until one level of narrowness

[image: rep graph at 120% of 1920x1080]

Beyond that level

[image: rep graph at 120% of 1920x1080]

Comment: Related bug report about the alignment of the progress bars in the badge tracker: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417426/badge-tracker-on-profile-wraps-oddly

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Answer with score 0 contains green background color but it's not marked as correct.
[image]

If I go to the **Answers** page, it is not seen as correct:
[image]

---

Another [bug](/questions/tagged/bug):

[image]

The date for this specific answer is outside the table view.

Comment: The first bug about green non-accepted answers is a dupe of [this report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372749/).

Comment: And the answer overflow issue is a dupe of [this report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372812#372812)

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

### Tooltip for tracking rep / privileges is too narrow.

Fix the many lines by having a larger tooltip, (or at least make them consistent by adding the missing newline between "and" and "a"!).

[image: The tooltip in question, with nearly every word on a separate line]

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Tooltip on view count missing in new layout.

Is [this feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360181/7920473) not implemented in new layout?

[image]

When I hover on the "5k views" nothing shows up in tooltip. Can this be a bug to be worked on?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

On the *Activity* -> *Summary* page, Answer timestamps isn't getting word wrapped and gets hidden under the questions.

[image: Overlap]

Using the regular [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome)

[image: Chrome Version]

Here's the bigger picture:

[image: Overlap bigger]

---

### Update

Seems it's not only the individual longer words, but at certain times the text wrappings doesn't happens at all.

[image: overlap_again]

Comment: Appears the title won't wrap propperly because it's one word.

Comment: @Luuklag Possibly you are right, I'm trying to look at the DOM, incase I can suggest something.

Comment: @Luuklag I think to wrap the longer words instead of _classname_ `v-truncate1` we need another _classname_ **`v-truncate2`**

Comment: Using `v-truncate2` will put it on two lines, but then the issue still persists for me, as the first word is too long for the answer box. So the size of the boxes should be set so that the timestamp takes prevalence over the title

Comment: @Luuklag Added one more observation which is a generic case.

Comment: [Already reported](/a/372812/289905).

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In Activity / Reputation changes of questions vs answer are not distinguished. So cannot distinguish question/answer rep in case if the question has self answer.

[image: Activity / Reputation]

Comment: How did I miss this?

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Tooltip for badges overflows the page width

Using Firefox for Android, the badges tooltip increases the page width beyond the screen resolution.

The tooltip:

[image: Activity page showing badge tooltip cut off]

Scrolled sideways to see the rest:

[image: Activity page scrolled sideways to see the badge tooltip]

Comment: I caught a similar cropped tooltip when hovering over the trophy icon next to some usernames FYI, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oSqE.png (originally raised as a bug [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415675/1225328)).

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There's a considerable amount of empty space below the *User feed* that serves no purpose and could be truncated to save scrolling.

[image: screenshot of space below user feed]

Comment: The bottom margins and padding really should be made consistent. There’s [41px on a Q&A page](//i.stack.imgur.com/Dlm7j.png), [24px on the Profile page](//i.stack.imgur.com/AgWnB.png), and [72px on the Activity page](//i.stack.imgur.com/BP0Bl.png). The yellow margin of the last one is 48px wide and comes from the `mb48` CSS class. Removing this class would make it [look like this](//i.stack.imgur.com/SCdQ3.png). Better?

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

There is a lot of white space if there is just one badge in Badges section in Summary tab.

[image: Screenshot of silver page from Badges section in Summary tab]

Please try to minimise the white space.

Comment: So if this box is next to the bronze badge box and that box has _three_ badges, how should this silver badge box look like? If the white space was removed, it would no longer line up with neighboring boxes at the bottom. What is your suggestion?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Maybe the size of the silver badge icon could be increased..

Comment: Maybe moving the badge to the top of the box (directly underneath the icon & heading) would feel more natural?

Comment: @RandomPerson Varying icon size feels more inconsistent.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Maybe the badge could be at the centre...

Comment: The problem is there are 3 groups of badge class and the text of having no badge takes up that amount of space, you can [see it in this screenshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372748). So there isn't really anything there to collapse because the 3 groups are always shown having the same height.

Answer (score 2):

On my profile:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/5314940/micha%c5%82-lipok
I can't click "hidden accounts"

[image]

Comment: What would you expect to happen if it was clickable?

Comment: Want to know what is hidden. Then I will know why is hidden.

Comment: Click on the View all 14 accounts link to the right.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I think it would be better in some instances to stretch the Badges section and shorten the Reputation section. Reason being the badges are visually more appealing because they have color and while the colored boxes currently look cramped the Reputation section looks overstretched.<sub>(Pictures taken on MSO.)</sub>

[image: screenshot rep badges impact sections]

Here's another interesting example

[image: screenshot rep badges impact sections 2]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

This might be related to the [Windows Segoe font having a lower baseline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372673#comment1244747_372673), but I thought it might be worth mentioning since the recent reputation gain in the summary section now has seemingly two equal elements with different alignments. The overall reputation gain and the tag reputation gain are showing differently.

[image: screenshot of recent rep gain in summary]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

It's noticeable in the track *Next tag badge* the score and answers title counters above the progress bars don't have the same alignment. This is seen clearly when put side by side.

[image: screenshot of track badge progress]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the Navigation drop down list the [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) are cut off. This happens for the `y` in Summary; for the `g` in Badges, Tags and Following; and for the `p` in Responses and Reputation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can we please have larger fonts in the "Select your next badge" dialogue? If the layout could be flexible starting at 3 columns it would also make it easier to get an overview of the badges.

[image: screenshot of select your next badge dialogue]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the Reputation page using the Graph tab the y-axis label has insufficient letter spacing. Some of the letters *"literally"* don't have any spacing between them causing reduced readability.

[image: screenshot of reputation graph in reputation page]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The scrollbar in the "Select next badge dialogue" doesn't have a margin separating it from the badges.

[image: screenshot of scrollbar in select next badge dialogue]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When viewing deleted questions, the votes aren't vertically aligned with the answers and view count:

[image]

Comment: Fun fact, all three boxes surrounding these numbers have different heights in pixels for me. 50 for votes, 49.3833 for answers and 52 for views

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

There seems to be a JavaScript bug. To reproduce:

1. First choose a different tag badge by clicking the cog in *Track tag badge* in the *REPUTATION* section.
2. Then try to choose another badge in the *Next badge* of the *BADGES* section. The second dialogue in the *Next badge* won't accept your choice and after a few clicks errors out with the message:

> The requested tag does not exist.

Notice the error message seems to imply it's referring to the choice in dialogue 1 but gets thrown when you're clicking in the other dialogue 2 (in that order).

[image: screenshot of summary section]

(I can't test this better because after a few clicks in both the badge choice dialogues I was [IP banned for too many requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297753) today. I wasn't using any userscripts so just a few clicks with vanilla browsing was enough to trigger the ban.)

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Building on the [Stacks color indicators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372477) I think the negative question record cross mark in the *BADGES* box of the *Summary* section should be red.

[image: screenshot negative question record]

Related issue [for the positive question record check mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375112). I'm following [Ben Kelly's advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081) to keep each item separate since these may be fixed at different times and dividing the reports makes it easier to mark them with a status change.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the *REPUTATION* box of the *Summary* section the Top tag and Next privilege progress bar aren't aligned on smaller resolutions. It ends up looking misaligned for no apparent reason.

[image: screenshot top tag and next privilege]

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I think the on hover background of the blue expand arrow of posts has insufficient contrast in the *All actions* tabs like *Revisions* and *Posts*. It would be more visible with a darker shade of blue.

[image: screenshot of blue expand arrow]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The tooltip for *Unfollow* has too much margin both in the *Summary* and the *Following* pages.

[image: screenshot of unfollow tooltip]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The reputation change indicator on your activity page does not include reputation restored from deleted posts, causing it to show an inaccurate number.

For example, the screenshot of my reputation page below shows -3, from 3 posts I downvoted since I last visited. However, I also gained 8 reputation from posts getting deleted, each of which I had downvoted at some point. This means that since I last visited my rep change is really +5, not -3.

Please fix this incorrect number:

[image: Screenshot with annotations highlighting the rep change indicator, what its value should actually be, and delineating each line change of reputation on the page so viewers can check my math, so to speak]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The dot on badge tags [aka *"the bling"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367459) in the Badges page appears cut on the sides (using responsive design and using zoom) in Firefox. This has the noteworthy property of only affecting bronze badges on the left-most column and silver badges in the middle column (can you believe it!?). (The elusive little dot does it again.)

[image: screenshot of badges]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64

**The wording in the "Tracking" cog's pop-up is inconsistent.**

Regardless of what is being tracked, the pop-up always gives the option to either:

> Track my next privilege
>
> Track a tag badge *instead*

[image]

**Q**: Shouldn't "*instead*" be on the privilege option if one is already tracking the tag badge - as in my screenshot?  (Or, in my opinion, deleted entirely as the highlight and tick make it obvious what the alternative is.)

Comment: Nice catch, this been pointed out once before [on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363041).

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the impact section the locked icons aren't aligned with the other items on the same line.

[image: screenshot of impact section]

Comment: More technical term: the baselines are misaligned.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the badges section the Newest title is slightly misaligned with the Next Badge titles. I don't know if this is on purpose and both elements are supposed to have different sizes but it adds a visual awkwardness.

[image: screenshot badges section]

Comment: Related to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372722) since it reported a previous misalignment.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the badges section of the summary page the badge names are too low within the badge. This was a change made after [December 12th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372869).

[image: screenshot of badge name]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The first line in the reputation mini graph has a smaller background than the other lines. It makes the fonts overflow the line compared with the others.

[image: screenshot rep mini graph]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Help text overflows the dialog box on *Activity* -> *Summary* page for the icon *Choose between choosing your next privilege and a tag badge*

[image: tag_badge]

Comment: [Already reported](/a/372632/289905).

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I don't know if this is browser specific but, in Firefox tab separators cab be slightly thicker at times when you're clicking through them although there's no clear pattern to it.

[image: screenshot tab separators]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The scores and the button text have different alignments when comparing the "Next privilege" modal in the Summary section and the "Next badge" in the Badges section.

[image: screenshot modals next privilege and next badge]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The "View all activity pages" has a small margin that becomes blurred by the outline after selecting the drop down list. This is also inconsistent with how the margins are spaced in the remaining sections.

[image: screenshot navigation drop down list and title]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

If you've cast 1 single reopen vote and the post is short (around 3 lines) the timestamp on the right side isn't put in its usual place below the bottom of the `<>` "less/greater than" characters. Instead the time stamp floats on the middle line of the post.

[image: screenshot of votes cast page]

Comment: Can we *please* do something in a general way to deal with the pluralization bug, come on... Also: should this count as a double-bug report? :)

Comment: @OlegValter I was thinking of grouping them under [tchrist's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374553) as a sort of sub-index...

Comment: yeah... Really tired of seeing this bug over, and over again. Either there should be a pluralization helper, or the stats should be formulated in pluralization-independent way, e.g. "Votes: 1", "Answers: 2", etc. This release has a *baffling* number of occurrences of this bug

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Tooltips in the impact section currently have different levels of alignment.

[image: screenshot of impact section tooltips]

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

In the summary section, currently the distance between the first cog and the label when tracking *"Next tag badge"* is different from if you're tracking *Next privilege* within the *REPUTATION* box. This last one also has the same spacing between cog and label as the *Next badge* in the *BADGES* box. I think it would be overall more consistent visually if the spacing between label and cog were the same for all 3 elements.

[image: screenshot of cogs and labels in summary section]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

If you use the dialogue to *Track tag badge* in the *REPUTATION* section a few times, after a while the on hover highlight on the exit button gets stuck. Afterwards when you enter the dialogue again the highlight is already there and doesn't change, it looks in fact slightly different with a second box around it from the normal hover.

(I wasn't able to determine the exact conditions to reproduce this but it happens fairly often.)

[image: screenshot of track next tag badge dialogue]

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Building on the [Stacks color indicators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372477) I think the positive question record check mark in the *BADGES* box of the *Summary* section should be green.

[image: screenshot positive question record]

Related issue [for the negative question record check mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375113). I'm following [Ben Kelly's advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081) to keep each item separate since these may be fixed at different times and dividing the reports makes it easier to mark them with a status change.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the *Accounts* section the site name is aligned lower than the rep and badge counts. Usually this could make sense but as it is I think the difference in alignments is a bit too much and ends up not looking good.

[image: screenshot of network accounts]

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I'm going to make a comparison of the same element in three different places. In the *Hidden communities* and *Accounts* sections you can see the site icons are on the same line but in the *YOUR COMMUNITIES* top bar the text is center aligned with the icon and the icon is larger than the text.

I would make the argument that having text and icon both center aligned looks better.

[image: screenshot of site icons and site names]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Going from low resolutions to very low resolutions the *Navigation* DDL title has the font size going below the font size of the *View all activity pages* underneath it. This seems like an edge case that's inconsistent with how titles/links are usually sized for the sections of the page.

**At low resolution**

[image: screenshot of Navigation title very res]

**At very low resolution**

[image: screenshot of Navigation title very small res]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The tooltip for *Remove bookmark* has too much margin both in the *Summary* and the *Bookmarks* pages.

[image: screenshot of remove bookmark tooltip]

Here's a screenshot of the *reputation* tooltip that has comparable length. (I include it because I had second thoughts if tooltips should have a minimum length that didn't depend on content.)

[image: screenshot of reputation tooltip]

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can we have the net score on the tag shown, instead of the reputation gain on it?

I could for example have a reputation gain of 10 on a tag with 2 upvotes and 5 downvotes. Then my tag score would effectively have a change of -3.

[image: Tag increments show the reputation gain on the tag]

Comment: It’s always shown the reputation gain. This is unrelated to the recent changes.

Comment: @SebastianSimon You believe this should be a separate Question?

Comment: Seems like a pretty creative feature request to me. +1

Comment: I think this is currently implemented with tool tips and all. I haven't played with it enough but I think it will look great. Can probably be marked status completed.

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the summary some section titles like Questions and Bookmarks and the link "View all N..." don't have the fonts starting in perfect alignment. It's noticeable both using responsive design and normal resolution. Using Windows 10 Firefox 95.0.1 (64-bit)  rev 2021.12.20.41044

[image]

Comment: This seems to be normal kerning. Both boxes have the same left boundary and the same font.

Answer (score -1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

If a user has 1 single answer it doesn't align with the center of the section.

[image: screenshot of answers and questions sections]

Comment: I think this is a consequence of [the empty sections taking up more space than single-item sections](/a/372747/289905) and the two boxes necessarily having to align at the bottom, in the current design, as can be seen in these reports: [1](/a/372809/289905), [2](/a/372737/289905), [3](/a/372777/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon in the terminology that's used regarding the summary of the profile page "a section" refers usually to "answers", "questions" (or "badges", etc) sections as shown in the screenshot. Regarding the CSS I would expect all sections, regardless if a section is empty or has 1 item, to have a flex container with the content center aligned. This specific case of a section with a single item hasn't been reported yet, and it's the kind of edge case that's always worth mentioning.

Answer (score -1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the track next badge dialogue the awarded badges aren't centered in their boxes.

[image: screenshot of select you next tag badge dialogue]

Answer (score -1):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

I've often asked myself: Is the check mark centered inside the circle of the  *"Congratulations! You've earned"* message...?

[image: screenshot of Congratulations! You've earned message]

**References:**

[What is the fastest way to find the "visual" center of an irregularly shaped polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1203135)

[Centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid)

Answer (score -2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The following is subtle but can be noticed (as usual, once you notice you can't take your eyes of it.)

In the reputation graph the bars are not evenly spaced. That means the white line separating the bars does not have the same width everywhere.

[image]

Using Windows 10, Firefox 95 (64-bit), 1920x1080, rev 2021.12.9.40958.

Comment: That's because you don't have a display monitor with infinite resolution. The bars have some particular width and they don't exactly divide into your particular display pixels evenly.

Comment: @RobertLongson implement a function that divides by resolution takes the modulus of pixels and pushes them to the edges instead of spuriously intertwining the remainder pixels between bars. It didn't used to look like this and I haven't change resolution. Isn't responsive design supposed to apply to every element in the UI?

Comment: You'll potentially get big gaps at one or other edge, and you'd need to determine the pixel resolution of the display which browsers won't necessarily tell you to prevent fingerprinting.

Comment: @RobertLongson fair enough on the fingerprinting, but if the edges are kept symmetric it's still a better solution than using different sizes of gaps between bars.

Comment: IIRC, SE *used to* manually specify each bar width and each gap (which hasn't been necessary for a long time, but was in old browsers when the page was first created). At this point, none of the bar widths or gaps are manually set. I'm unsure when that changed (as I'd already fixed it in the CSS I applied to those pages in order to have them be responsive with the old layout, so didn't notice a change). I suspect it changed with the redesign, at least one of the redesigns, but it might have been after this report as a resolution to this issue. You should check to see if this is still an issue.

Comment: @RobertL *At this point*, unless the browser intentionally degrades the rendered display to prevent tertiary methods of determining the viewport width, then it has nothing to do with preventing fingerprinting. Browsers *usually* display things correctly and just report wrong, or no, information to JavaScript. The way SE now does that reputation graph relies *entirely* on the browser choosing equal bar widths and equally applying the specified gap (specified only once by SE for all of the bars). So, now, any inconsistency in the bar width or the inter-bar gap is *entirely* in the browser.

Answer (score -2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

In the tabs of the All actions page can we have more use of colors in the labels? Something to make fuller use of the Stacks component indicators.

> Quoting Aaron Shekey from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372477)
>
> We switched to a new Stacks component, **which is how indicators like this will look moving forward. By switching, it allows them to be themed, and the color** red is generally reserved for errors.

This can also have the practical use of aiding in to visually inspect  lists. Mods and power users have asked for other visual queues that help [differentiate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343923).

[image: screenshot of All actions' tabs]

Comment: I am very much in favour of not making a christmas tree here. The wording is clear enough. The only thing that disturbs me in this screenshot is the use of capitals for the outcome, while not for the action (suggested, reviewed) that was taken.

Comment: Mods and power users asked for more color in the tooling. Dark mode is full of color.

Comment: At least all the information is there. You can do it yourself with a script.

Comment: what about accessibility for colorblind?

Comment: @java-addict301 what about it? Accessibility isn't reduced for the colorblind by the site's current use of color. Or is it? You tell me.

Answer (score -2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the "Choose which tag badge to track" window, there's a text that reads:

> showing top 100 of 161 available badges; please use the search box to find a specific badge

Looking at the Stacks content guidelines for [periods and semicolons](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#periods) I think the first letter should be capitalized and there should also be a period. That would be consistent with the other long sentences in the empty sections of the profile page.

[image: screenshot track next badge dialogue 1]

The text should also be centered when the number of badges varies. Compare the text placement when there are no badges and when there are no badges.

[image: screenshot track next badge dialogue 2]

Comment: This is not one of the new changes. Also, the positioning has been reported here already: [Tag badge tracker - "showing top 100 of x available badges" text is in the wrong position](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354690/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon The devs asked for anything from the activity page, so this is from the activity page. On focus with what the devs asked: *"if you find anything broken, missing, or out of place, please let us know. We appreciate it!"*

Comment: The dialog didn’t change at all, though.

Comment: The fact that this dialog is not yet responsive is a different issue which has been [reported by Suraj Rao](/a/372751/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon for the readers sake it's probably best if you delete the comments now, this has changed in the meanwhile and is partly done (requires the full stop and capitalizing the first letter).

Answer (score -3):

I do not see all reputation history graph lines

https://stackexchange.com/users/6922986/micha%c5%82-lipok?tab=reputation

[image]

As you can see in the following screenshot I have some reputation points on other sites:
https://stackexchange.com/users/6922986/micha%c5%82-lipok?tab=accounts

[image]

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to be about the activity page in the user profile.

Comment: Url relates it to user profile.

Comment: But in fact it opens after I click in network profile, while I was in user profile

Comment: This isn’t a bug. See [Reputation line graph only has one of three lines](/q/109985/289905). This is the network profile, not the activity page. Your post is unrelated to the recent changes.

Answer (score -5):

There's also no net reputation change for Sep 10th, 11th nor on the 12th. Does the showing of a 0-change for the 8th mean something happened?

- If so, what?
- If not, why is it there?

[image: Shows "There were no net reputation changes on this day" for Sep. 8th. While there are no entries at all between the 9th and the 13th]

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is known behaviour for the old UI (perhaps even [tag:status-bydesign]).

Comment: I see. Thank you. It still doesn't make any sense to me :) I have no idea what happened on Sep 8th that gives me a no-reputation change. I can see this on other user's profiles as well.

Comment: This may provide some insight: ["No reputation changes on this day"... OK, why did you tell me this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154846/295232)

Comment: I was just reading that post :) "it's also technically very hard to remove" seems like a very odd reason. I mean, I can make a user script to remove everything that has a zero-change with no children. Not seeing how that's "technically very hard".

Comment: I don't think that this is scoped to the current design changes, as this is already existing behaviour that hasn't changed anything. Voting to delete this answer.