# Misalignment of summary data in my Activity Questions sub-menu

Tags: bug, profile-page

Android<sup>1</sup> phone in "full site" view:

The whole line summarising a question in my [Activity Questions page](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/35069/rock-ape?tab=questions) is misaligned and nudged to the left when that question's title goes on to a second line.

(Niether changing to desktop view nor dis/enabling responsiveness makes any difference.)[image]

<sup>1</sup> Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro

Comment: Can't replicate on my phone - I'm running android 11 on  oneplus 9 pro 2340x1080...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks for looking in to this but it's now fixed, presumably following the recent updates to the Activity page. Would that make it Status Complete?