# Stack Overflow - Revert back to the GUI layout prior to the launch of the December 8th, 2021, version

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, user-interface

How do I revert the SO GUI layout change back to prior 8 December 2021 version?

1. The current "scroll" version is hideously large
2. It does not sum the key ingredients on a 27" screen in a single point of view.

Please implement "choice"!

Comment: Not really. At the link as proposed answer there is a lot of detailed feedback and lots of in-depth discussion but no solution that provides the user/client/contributor to keep the horizontal and "condensed" summarized layout. This questions the use of cookies at all. Especially for small screens. This now feels like a Windows 7 GUI to Windows 8 change; the magical introduction "windows tiles" because we swap massively to mobile devices. Long story short.. they reverted back whereas some folks advice to give the user "freedom" in GUI choice.

Comment: I'm guessing your only option at the moment will be a userscript. It may be worth it to keep this question open in case someone decides to make (and post) one. But there aren't any built-in options on SE to do this.

Comment: Look like it but the old layout isn't gone. So my guess is that Jarrod or crew-members posts an answer where we can get a copy/download such script?

Comment: So add that feedback as an answer to the suggested duplicate i.e. that you want a condensed layout on wide screens if you think such an answer isn't currently present and would be useful.

Comment: @RobertLongson, you want me to do this here or at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1244468_372049 not much we can do, except downvote that post, hopefully if it reach something like -800 they'll revert the change, or try to improve based on the feedback...

Comment: I think it was on 2021-12-07 (in almost all time zones), not 2021-12-08. Definitely 2021-12-07 in UTC.

Comment: It isn't restricted to Stack Overflow, as far as I know. It is for all Stack Exchange sites, including the ones you [have](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/users/2025/peter-mortensen?tab=bookmarks) [never](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tour) [heard](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/tour) [of](https://iota.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: All the layout changes in the last months were not reverted, even the massively downvoted ones (line height, blockquotes, fonts, etc). SE keeps doing whatever they want and doesn't really care about community's feedback anymore. I really doubt they will reverse that, I guess we'll just have to live with it and hope someone creates a nice userscript...