# Determine if a bug reported on a foreign language Stack Exchange site is already reported on Meta.SE

Tags: support, search, meta, languages, responsive-design

I created a post on Stack Overflow en Español and no one has given me an answer; it appears it is a bug that they cannot solve... In chat they suggested I come to Meta.SE and post it, and I came across this post:

[New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page)

I'm inexperienced with English to express and interpret the posts; I am concerned that I want to help by reporting something but that the language barrier could be a problem and that I'd get negative feedback for trying to help; this is my post in Spanish:

[Efectos detectados en el cambio del diseño del sitio en español:](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5332/efectos-detectados-en-el-cambio-del-dise%c3%b1o-del-sitio-en-espa%c3%b1ol)

How can I determine if this post has already been reported by someone else?

Are the bugs found on the Spanish site the same as those reported on Meta.SE?

Comment: I feel like this hasn't been mentioned: questions being duplicates *aren't* a bad thing - in fact, especially in this case, they're good. The point of the duplicates system is to link together questions that have the same answer, even if those questions have different search terms. If someone if more familiar with Spanish than English, your question will help them navigate to the "canonical" answer if they search for terms in Spanish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug you found was reported in this answer [+2 for Wiki Tag Edit does not show text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372600). (The title of the answer was taken from the [index post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372698).)

You raise a very valid question:

> I am concerned that I want to help by reporting something and that **the language barrier (...) How I can determine if this post has already been reported by someone else?**

In such cases you have to search by keywords (tag, wiki, edit, reputation) using the index post, or using the search function for the question, e.g. [`inquestion:372049 tag wiki edit reputation`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion:372049+tag+wiki+edit+reputation) and refining the search results from there.

> English language to express and interpret the posts; **I am concerned**

There are speakers of many languages on the site and we try to work with other posters by editing, clarifying, explaining. So please don't be worried about the language barrier in participating. In this case just narrow your search using the keywords to make sure your post isn't a duplicate and the community will help you with everything else.

> Are the bugs found on the Spanish site the same as those reported on Meta.SE?

Yes, these changes in SE's software were deployed network wide.

[Saludos o/](https://www.google.com/search?q=saludos)