# Tooltip text is lengthier than its background

Tags: bug, tooltips, activity, activity-summary

Under the summary section of the activity page, the tooltip for one of the gear icons is messed up. The text ("Choose between tracking your next privilege and a tag badge") is lengthier than its background, thereby giving the effect that the text overflows the background element.

[image]

OS: Windows 10
Browser: MS Edge

Comment: @mods should this also go as an answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page?

Comment: possibly related/opposite: [tooltip bug report on responsive activity page meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373027/341145)

Comment: @SamOnela not a dupe.

Comment: I didn't mean its a duplicate, rather just that it is related.

Comment: Please add browser/OS details to the question.

Comment: I think it's the same [as this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372613) on the "New responsive Activity page" thread.

Comment: and specifically https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374463/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372632/282094