# Badge symbol on activity page "Next Badge" progress out of place

Tags: bug, activity

The little gold badge symbol in the progress bar is out of place on the activity page.

[image]

I think it is supposed to look something like this (check out my ms paint skills):

[image]

Or possibly like this:

[image]

Comment: This has been reported as a [tag:bug] as part of the ongoing development of the activity page. See [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373043/168244).