# Next badge silver badge clipping off of the bar

Tags: bug, profile-page

[image]

In my profile, for some reason, the silver badge next to the "Next badge" section is clipping off of the bar.

Is this a known bug? Is it intentional?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page) (specifically [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373043/355458) answer)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I don't see my bug on that list, but I could be mistaken. Edit: Yup there it is. Thanks.

Comment: lol I [asked about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374124/badge-symbol-on-activity-page-next-badge-progress-out-of-place) yesterday.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Oops :(