# Stackoverflow's User's activity page shows answer as accepted when it's not really accepted

Tags: bug, profile-page, accepted-answer

I've been noticing this since the last 5 hours. Activity page shows the answer in green which means "accepted", but when I open the answer, it's not accepted. Please refer to the screenshots:

[image: Answers list in profile showing "1" in green next to the title of a question]

That's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70389954/substract-pandas-dataframes-with-different-indices/70389980#70389980).

[image: answer is not accepted]

Seems most likely a temp glitch on SO side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page). Some of the answers there have already reported this bug :)