# "Approved and Leave Closed" overlaps with the post title in the activity tab

Tags: bug, design, review, profile-page, activity

The bug is the title.

Screenshot:

[image]

I chose "Approve and Leave Closed", but the text is overlapping with the title of the post I reviewed.

It looks bad... It's a bug surely.

Comment: *stares at the Zalgo username overlapping the "asked # minutes ago" message*

Comment: @SPArcheon Lol, F̉͋̅̾̇

Comment: Already reported [in this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372732)