# Winterbash Leaderboard larger usernames not getting wrapped

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

Winterbash Leaderboard larger usernames not getting word wrapped

[image: wrap]

Possibly same issue as [On the Activity -> Summary page, Answer timestamps isn't getting word wrapped and gets hidden under the questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374369/379623)