# Include tag name for tag wiki edits in the reputation history

Tags: feature-request, design, reputation-history

Report related to this change:

- Bug: [+2 for Wiki Tag Edit does not show text.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372600/925996)

I think it is not a bug; rather, it is that something is missing in a certain place!
Apparently, the reported problem in which the text was not visible was corrected; I even included the feature to add which tag was edited/approved (on user profile view).

But in the reputation section, you still see the text without the tag name. When checking Transifex to validate the translation, it indicates that the variable has not been added to the text output `$tags$`.

[image: Screenshot of Reputation section of a user's Activity page (in Spanish), showing 2 tag wiki edits from Dec. 17th. Both merely read "editar: wiki de etiqueta" ("edit: tag wiki").]

("editar" means "edit", and "wiki de etiqueta" means "tag wiki". There is no indication of which tag's wiki was edited. This text is shown regardless of whether the tag wiki or the tag excerpt was edited.)

I did not find this report in the bug list.

Comment: status of request?? https://i.imgur.com/jKaHb89.png