# English numeric-agreement bugs in the user profile questions tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, localization, plurals, english

When viewing the results of the question tab for a user profile, you are presented with grammatically incorrect English. It erroneously uses plural count nouns following a count of one:

[image: Example of en.SO profile questions with grammatically incorrect English]

The same holds true for all the other count nouns displayable on that tab, and on the answers tab as well.

This numeric-agreement bug only exists in the English UI; it is, for example, absent from the Spanish UI, which actually knows how to construct grammatically correct Spanish:

[image: Example of es.SO profile questions with grammatically correct Spanish]

I guarantee that you would have no end of helpful volunteers from [*English Language & Usage*](https://english.stackexchange.com/) if you decide the best way to fix all these is to send the English UI strings through [Transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transifex). :)

Comment: Some of the pluralization issues have already been reported in [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page) which has a huge list of bugs and feature requests. You are likely to find that your list is redundant

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed, although the bookmark count has been removed from those listings. The following screenshot shows a current example:

[image: screenshot of question and answers page in user profile]

(End note: finding a post with exactly 1 view isn't easy!)