# Comment excerpts missing on "All actions" section of user "Activity" tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, activity

**All actions** used to include an excerpt of comments, but now they're missing. Is this a bug or an intentional change?

If it's intentional, why? I use **All actions** to follow up on comments I left on new user posts, but this change makes that harder to do.

Screenshot of mine on SO:
[image: screenshot showing comments and revisions in "All actions", with comment content missing]

(They're also missing from the **Comments** tab. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPgqU.png))

I don't have a screenshot from before, but here's one [from Glorfindel](https://stackapps.com/q/8378/79263) showing edit summaries, which the comment excerpts looked similar to:
[image: screenshot showing revisions in "All actions", with edit summaries included]

I noticed edit summaries were removed in this change as well, but that's less important to me, and you can click the "expand" arrow to show them anyway.

Comment: The previous profile page layout used to show the *entire* comment, not just an excerpt. I'd want this prior behavior reinstated, since I often used it to find text I previously posted at the end of a comment, which is no longer possible.

Comment: @Sonic I think you could use a SEDE query instead. Check out [this Meta SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333733/4518341). That'd probably be easier anyway -- instead of Ctrl-F, next page, Ctrl-F, next page, etc, you just put in the query and it'll find all matches.

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah, that works for old comments, but doesn't work for newer ones since SEDE is only updated once a week. Many times when I used to do that, I was looking for a word in a newer comment, not an older one. This also meant fewer pages to search.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was not an intentional change and a fix for this bug has been shipped. Good catch @wjandrea!

In the process of updating the layout for the Reputation section of Activity, comment text was moved into an expandable section that *isn't rendered on comments*. I've moved the comment text out of that expandable section to match the data in the previous iteration of the layout.

I've marked this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) since I've shipped the fix to here on Meta and will be shipping it network-wide shortly.

**Update:** It's out network-wide now.

---

[Comment posted before shipping the fix for further info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376539/comment-excerpts-missing-on-all-actions-section-of-user-activity-tab#comment1255046_376539):

> The comment and the revision detail are in fact missing from this view. Most of the data for these items got moved into an expandable section but comments aren't expandable. Revision details are visible, but only after expanding the item. I have a fix for both those issues in the works that should ship within 24 hours. Thanks for the clear and thoughtful bug report!

Comment: I can confirm I'm seeing the change here on MSE and on SO. And the edit summaries are back too.

Comment: Suggested edits still do not include the text, and are not expandable.