# Inconsistent whitespace between statistics and tooltips in the Impact summary

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, tooltips, summary

On the Activity page, in the Summary subtab, there seems to be an inconsistency in the amount of whitespace between the statistics and tooltips in the Impact summary. The spacing is fine between the "helpful flags" statistic and it's tooltip:

[image]

However, for the "people reached" and "votes cast" statistics, there's an extra amount of whitespace between each statistic and it's tooltip:

- "people reached" and it's tooltip:

  [image]
- "votes cast" and it's tooltip:

  [image]

Comment: Was previously [reported in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374902)