# Minor alignment issue in Activity page Impact section's tooltip

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, tooltips

There is an alignment issue in the [Activity page Impact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=summary) section's tooltip for the "people reached" and "votes cast" captions.

The tooltip is displayed correctly for the "helpful flags" caption.

[image: Correct tooltip]

But for the "people reached" and "votes cast" captions the tooltip is displayed a little below.
I guess, for these two sections the tooltip is displayed after the div section ends.

[image: Tooltip issue]

[image: Tooltip issue]

Comment: This one has been reported twice if I'm not mistaken. [The initial report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374902) and [another report later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377289).

Comment: I agree this is a dupe, but I don't think it makes sense to dupe close it against the activity page announcement anymore, since I'd assume that's not really getting checked anymore given it's been 8 months.