# Alignment issue in the toggle for tracking a tag badge/next privilege

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

There's an alignment issue in the toggle for tracking a tag badge/next privilege:

> [image: Image of "track a tag badge instead" misaligned // green tick mark is next to the first option]

> [image: Image of "track a tag badge instead" misaligned // green tick mark is next to the second option]

Comment: This misalignment bug is new, [it has not been reported before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372698) on MSE or MSO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed! Looks like we didn't account for multiple lines in the dropdown menu; now we do for this one.

[image]