# Votes cast statistic "{ } this week" is not aligned properly in the full site on mobile

Tags: bug, responsive-design, mobile-chrome, activity-summary

The Votes cast statistic "{ } this week" in the [Summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/513150/justin) tab is not aligned properly in the full site on mobile:

> [image]

On PC/desktop, it's correctly aligned:

> [image]

I also tried [landscape view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8uxV.jpg), but the issue still persists.

This occurs on Chrome for Android.

---

Expected result:

> [image]

Comment: There is a media query `@media (max-width: 980px)` that completely screws everything up

Comment: Previously reported [in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372872)

Comment: @bad_coder: That specific bug you reported occurs on PC/desktop, where zooming in affects the alignment (at 100% it's correctly aligned; at 175% and above, the alignment is off). In the *full site on mobile*, this issue occurs regardless of the zoom level.

Comment: @Justin that wasn't using zoom but the responsiveness, meaning resizing the display area. In principle being responsive the CSS should be exactly the same across devices. Like Oleg says, the formatting depends only on width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items in the "Votes cast" summary are laid out using the [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) model. The container element consists of two rows of items ("upvotes", "downvotes", "question votes", "answer votes" and "this month", "this week", "today" in the second respectively), each its own flex container (set with the [`d-flex`](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/flex/#basic-flex-layout) Stacks class).

To ensure proper column alignment, each row has the [`flex__allitems3`](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/flex/#fixed-cells) Stacks class set on it that sets the `flex-basis` CSS property to `calc(25% - var(--su16));` for all items (indicated via the `flex--item` Stacks class) which sets the initial width of items roughly equal to ¼th of the width of the container.

This is enough for the elements to be aligned properly (as evidenced by the alignment on larger screens). However, each row also has the `md:jc-space-between` Stacks class which is the source of the issue. The [`jc-space-between`](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/flex/#justify-content) Stacks class simply applies the `justify-content: space-between;` rule to the flex container, and the `md:` prefix makes it scoped to medium-sized screens or less.

And wherein lies the problem — the abovementioned class adds a media query with two problematic rulesets that kicks in for viewport widths less than 980px:

```css
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  html.html__responsive:not(.html__unpinned-leftnav) .md\:jc-space-between {
    justify-content: space-between !important;
  }

  html.html__responsive:not(.html__unpinned-leftnav) .md\:fl-auto {
    flex: 1 1 auto !important;
  }
}
```

Of note is the shorthand [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) CSS property and it its third value which ensures that the `flex-basis` is overridden to `auto`. Combined with [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) set to `1` and `justify-content` also being overridden to `space-between`, the media query causes the items to stretch resulting in what you observe.

Case in point, compare the component with the query disabled and without.

With:

[image: component with the query disabled]

Without:

[image: component without the query disabled]

Give it [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/786798).