# Question is now closed - text not vertically centered in box

Tags: bug, design, error-message

I noticed the following message isn't vertically centered in the box, but I think it would look better if it did.

> This question is now closed - please refresh the page for updated status.

[image: screenshot of warning message]

Comment: What's that peculiar red line that's doubled over the right side?

Comment: @LittlePickle. I usually add a red line to highlight misalignment, the lower one approximately marks the center for comparison. The second line slightly above is where the text and close button are on (it might be Windows Segoe specific, see the comment [under this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372673)).

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just used to seeing those things drawn [freehand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) on meta.