# Cannot unfollow a post that is also bookmarked from profile summary page without unbookmarking first

Tags: bug, profile-page, bookmarks, follow-post

I have a post that I have both followed and bookmarked. (I was doing some unrelated testing).

[image]

When attempting to unfollow the post from my profile summary page I was presented with the option to "Remove Bookmark"

[image]

I was unsure if this was simply a typographical error or a functional one so I clicked the button. It did, indeed, *unbookmark* this post and left it in the following state. It does give the option to re-bookmark the post immediately:

[image]

---

After refreshing the page this is what it looks like. Note that the post is no longer in the bookmarks section, but remains in following.

[image]

Now that the post is no longer bookmarked, I am now able to unfollow the post:

[image]

Can this be fixed so that it is possible to unfollow posts from the profile summary page without having to unbookmark them first?

Comment: I mean... not that I could find before posting this and not that came up in the list of similar questions in the ask window. That said, searching for meta posts is regularly a struggle for me so not being able to find an existing report doesn't mean it's not out there. If it has been asked before it's an easy enough fix to close it as a duplicate ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That was the first place I checked and I did not find anything related to this specific issue. There are 217 (undeleted) answers so always possible I could've missed it.

Comment: Yeah it's a tough thread, by using the `inquestion:372049` operator in search together with `unfollow` or `unbookmark` narrows it down (sometimes you have to click the link, and then enter a second time for the anchor to take you to the right post). This [report by Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372645) was marked `status-completed` a part of what he reported was solved but it says in the comments that not everything. This report seems like a detailed follow up on the part that wasn't completely fixed.

Comment: Again, I am familiar with the search features that exist. I saw Glorfindel's post (which you've linked) but that report seems to be about unfollow from the Summary not working at all which would be a distinct issue from this behaviour. Though I agree that it is possible that this new behaviour  could have been caused by whatever fix was done there. In which case it could be a followup in that respect.

Comment: I agree, this takes the previous report a step further. Good post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed. Followed posts (which are also bookmarked) can now be unfollowed from the summary page without having to unbookmark them first:

[image]